# What is the difference between call and apply?

Tags: javascript, function, performance

What is the difference between using `Function.prototype.apply()` and `Function.prototype.call()` to invoke a function?

```js
const func = function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
};
```

`func.apply()` vs. `func.call()`

Are there performance differences between the two aforementioned methods? When is it best to use `call` over `apply` and vice versa?

Comment: Think of `a` in apply for array of args and `c` in call for columns of args.

Comment: @LarryBattle I do almost the same, but I think a in apply for array and c in call for comma (i.e comma separated arguments).

Comment: I agree it's stupid. What's annoying is that somehow this question gets asked during interviews because some influential chump added the question to their list of important js questions.

Comment: the default "arguments" array that gets passed into a function's scope gets passed on with apply. arguments goes with array goes with apply, call accepts a manual list of models, not a collection object (array)

Comment: You *apply* for a job once (one argument), you [phone] *call* people many times (several arguments). Alternative: there are [too?] many *Call* of Duty games.

Comment: More classic, there's only one array, you *apply* it [as a whole], there're several arguments, you *call* them [in a row]. Take your pick :)

Comment: When the intention is to invoke a variadic function with a list of argument values regardless of "this" value, then use the ES6 spread operator, e.g. `fn(...input)` where input is an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: If you use "apply" or "call" only to chenge the "this" reference, and the function you refer to will not take any arguments, there is no diference what so ever.

Comment: In ES6, if you've got an array of arguments `args`, only difference would be of three dots `...`. **ie:** `fn.apply(context, args)` or `fn.call(context, ...args)`

Answer (score 4017, accepted):

The difference is that `apply` lets you invoke the function with `arguments` as an array; `call` requires the parameters be listed explicitly. A useful mnemonic is *"**A** for **a**rray and **C** for **c**omma."*

See MDN's documentation on [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Pseudo syntax:

`theFunction.apply(valueForThis, arrayOfArgs)`

`theFunction.call(valueForThis, arg1, arg2, ...)`

There is also, as of ES6, the possibility to [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the array for use with the `call` function, you can see the compatibilities [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Sample code:

```js
function theFunction(name, profession) {
    console.log("My name is " + name + " and I am a " + profession +".");
}
theFunction("John", "fireman");
theFunction.apply(undefined, ["Susan", "school teacher"]);
theFunction.call(undefined, "Claude", "mathematician");
theFunction.call(undefined, ...["Matthew", "physicist"]); // used with the spread operator
```

Comment: Are they both supported by the majority of browsers? I seem to remember reading that `call()` was more of an IE thing.

Comment: One thing to add is that the args must be a numerical array ([]).  Associative arrays ({}) will not work.

Comment: @KevinSchroeder: In javascript parlance, `[]` is called an **array**, `{}` is called an **object**.

Comment: I often used to forget which takes an array, and which expects you to list the arguments. A technique I used to remember it is if the first letter of the method starts with **a** then it takes an array i.e  **a** pply array

Comment: @SAM Using _call_ instead of a normal function call only makes sense if you need to change the value of _this_ for the function call. An example (that convert a functions arguments-object to an array): `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` or `[].slice.call(arguments)`. _apply_ makes sense if you have the arguments in an array, for example in a function that calls another function with (almost) the same parameters. **Recommendation** Use a normal function call `funcname(arg1)` if that does what you need, and save _call_ and _apply_ for those special occasions when you really need them.

Comment: `theFunction.call(undefined, ["Claude", "mathematician"]); // 'My name is Claude,mathematician and I am a undefined.'`
Oh Claude! <3

(https://photos-5.dropbox.com/t/1/AABRnQkgeaYomPlRZXK3rX3cc83efluhOVMqei2B3xCkGg/12/781400/png/1024x768/3/1415624400/0/2/Screenshot%202014-11-10%2011.32.52.png/ZxDPt6a1JoHLQz55W1pab-y4cW0tBMZAUHQV2e3i1oQ)

Comment: theFunction.apply(undefined, ["Susan", "school teacher"]);
theFunction.call(undefined, "Claude", "mathematician");   Why the first argument is undefined while calling?

Comment: @KunalSingh Both `call` and `apply` takes two parameters. The first argument of `apply' and `call` function must be the owner object and the second parameter will be array or comma separated  parameters respectively. If you pass `null` or `undefined` as first argument then in non-strict mode they are replaced with global object i.e. `window`

Comment: # codes bugs ```theFunction.apply(undefined, ...["Matthew", "physicist"]); ``` [A_better_apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_apply)

Comment: The mnemonic alone is worth the answer. I don't think I'll need to look it up again!

Comment: @AJQarshi @KunalSingh Just to expound on Qarshi's answer, the first argument, owner object, as he called it, is the execution context you want to pass to the function(`this` context). When an object is passed as argument, then the function invoked is bound to the object's execution context and any reference to members in the function will indeed point to existing object members. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @candy_man why would someone want to pass in the execution context?  What is the purpose of the first argument exactly?

Answer (score 257):

K. Scott Allen has [a nice writeup](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/04/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) on the matter.

Basically, they differ on how they handle function arguments.

> The apply() method is identical to call(), except apply() requires an array as the second parameter. The array represents the arguments for the target method."

So:

```
// assuming you have f
function f(message) { ... }
f.call(receiver, "test");
f.apply(receiver, ["test"]);
```

Comment: the second parameter of apply() and call() is optional, not required.

Comment: First parameter is not required too.

Comment: @Ikrom, the first parameter is not required for `call` but a requirement for  `apply`

Answer (score 172):

To answer the part about when to use each function, use `apply` if you don't know the number of arguments you will be passing, or if they are already in an array or array-like object (like the `arguments` object to forward your own arguments. Use `call` otherwise, since there's no need to wrap the arguments in an array.

```
f.call(thisObject, a, b, c); // Fixed number of arguments

f.apply(thisObject, arguments); // Forward this function's arguments

var args = [];
while (...) {
    args.push(some_value());
}
f.apply(thisObject, args); // Unknown number of arguments
```

When I'm not passing any arguments (like your example), I prefer `call` since I'm *calling* the function. `apply` would imply you are *applying* the function to the (non-existent) arguments.

There shouldn't be any performance differences, except maybe if you use `apply` and wrap the arguments in an array (e.g. `f.apply(thisObject, [a, b, c])` instead of `f.call(thisObject, a, b, c)`). I haven't tested it, so there could be differences, but it would be very browser specific. It's likely that `call` is faster if you don't already have the arguments in an array and `apply` is faster if you do.

Answer (score 126):

Here's a good mnemonic.  **A**pply uses **A**rrays and **A**lways takes one or two Arguments.  When you use **C**all you have to **C**ount the number of arguments.

Comment: Useful mnemonic right there!. I will change the 'one or two Arguments' to say 'a maximum of two Arguments' since neither the first or the second parameters of `apply` is required. I'm not sure though why one will call `apply` or `call` without a parameter. Looks like someone is trying to find out why here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903782/call-apply-with-no-parameters-vs-simply-calling-a-function-with-paran

Answer (score 98):

While this is an old topic, I just wanted to point out that .call is slightly faster than .apply. I can't tell you exactly why.

See jsPerf, http://jsperf.com/test-call-vs-apply/3

---

[`UPDATE!`]

Douglas Crockford mentions briefly the difference between the two, which may help explain the performance difference... http://youtu.be/ya4UHuXNygM?t=15m52s

Apply takes an array of arguments, while Call takes zero or more individual parameters! Ah hah!

`.apply(this, [...])`

`.call(this, param1, param2, param3, param4...)`

Comment: This depends on what the function does with the parameters/array, if it doesn't need to process the array, does it take less time?

Comment: Interestingly even without the array, call is still much faster. http://jsperf.com/applyvscallvsfn2

Comment: @JoshMc That would be very browser specific. In IE 11, I'm getting apply going twice as fast as call.

Comment: 1. Creating a new array means the garbage collector will need to clean it up at some point.  2. Accessing items in the array using dereference is less efficient than accessing a variable (parameter) directly.  (I believe that is what kmatheny meant by "parsing", which is actually something quite different.)  But neither of my arguments explain the jsperf.  That must be related to the engine's implementation of the two functions, e.g. perhaps they create an empty array anyway, if none was passed.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the test and video

Answer (score 81):

Follows an extract from [Closure: The Definitive Guide by Michael Bolin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871). It might look a bit lengthy, but it's saturated with a lot of insight. From "Appendix B. Frequently Misunderstood JavaScript Concepts":

---

## What `this` Refers to When a Function is Called

When calling a function of the form `foo.bar.baz()`, the object `foo.bar` is referred to as the receiver. When the function is called, it is the receiver that is used as the value for `this`:

```
var obj = {};
obj.value = 10;
/** @param {...number} additionalValues */
obj.addValues = function(additionalValues) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    this.value += arguments[i];
  }
  return this.value;
};
// Evaluates to 30 because obj is used as the value for 'this' when
// obj.addValues() is called, so obj.value becomes 10 + 20.
obj.addValues(20);
```

If there is no explicit receiver when a function is called, then the global object becomes the receiver. As explained in "goog.global" on page 47, window is the global object when JavaScript is executed in a web browser. This leads to some surprising behavior:

```
var f = obj.addValues;
// Evaluates to NaN because window is used as the value for 'this' when
// f() is called. Because and window.value is undefined, adding a number to
// it results in NaN.
f(20);
// This also has the unintentional side effect of adding a value to window:
alert(window.value); // Alerts NaN
```

Even though `obj.addValues` and `f` refer to the same function, they behave differently when called because the value of the receiver is different in each call. For this reason, when calling a function that refers to `this`, it is important to ensure that `this` will have the correct value when it is called. To be clear, if `this` were not referenced in the function body, then the behavior of `f(20)` and `obj.addValues(20)` would be the same.

Because functions are first-class objects in JavaScript, they can have their own methods. All functions have the methods `call()` and `apply()` which make it possible to redefine the receiver (i.e., the object that `this` refers to) when calling the function. The method signatures are as follows:

```
/**
* @param {*=} receiver to substitute for 'this'
* @param {...} parameters to use as arguments to the function
*/
Function.prototype.call;
/**
* @param {*=} receiver to substitute for 'this'
* @param {Array} parameters to use as arguments to the function
*/
Function.prototype.apply;
```

Note that the only difference between `call()` and `apply()` is that `call()` receives the function parameters as individual arguments, whereas `apply()` receives them as a single array:

```
// When f is called with obj as its receiver, it behaves the same as calling
// obj.addValues(). Both of the following increase obj.value by 60:
f.call(obj, 10, 20, 30);
f.apply(obj, [10, 20, 30]);
```

The following calls are equivalent, as `f` and `obj.addValues` refer to the same function:

```
obj.addValues.call(obj, 10, 20, 30);
obj.addValues.apply(obj, [10, 20, 30]);
```

However, since neither `call()` nor `apply()` uses the value of its own receiver to substitute for the receiver argument when it is unspecified, the following will not work:

```
// Both statements evaluate to NaN
obj.addValues.call(undefined, 10, 20, 30);
obj.addValues.apply(undefined, [10, 20, 30]);
```

The value of `this` can never be `null` or `undefined` when a function is called. When `null` or `undefined` is supplied as the receiver to `call()` or `apply()`, the global object is used as the value for receiver instead. Therefore, the previous code has the same undesirable side effect of adding a property named `value` to the global object.

It may be helpful to think of a function as having no knowledge of the variable to which it is assigned. This helps reinforce the idea that the value of this will be bound when the function is called rather than when it is defined.

---

End of extract.

Comment: Just to note the fact, that `additionalValues` is not referenced inside `obj.addValues` body

Comment: I know you were answering the question but would like to add: you could have used bind when defining f.

`var f = obj.addValues;`
becomes
`var f = obj.addValues.bind(obj)` 

and now f(20) would work without having to use call or apply every time.

Comment: I know you didn't write it, but you did highlight the text and examples from the book as relevant, and I am very grateful. They were very helpful.

Answer (score 37):

It is useful at times for one object to borrow the function of another object, meaning that the borrowing object simply executes the lent function as if it were its own.

**A small code example:**

```
var friend = {
    car: false,
    lendCar: function ( canLend ){
      this.car = canLend;
 }

}; 

var me = {
    car: false,
    gotCar: function(){
      return this.car === true;
  }
};

console.log(me.gotCar()); // false

friend.lendCar.call(me, true); 

console.log(me.gotCar()); // true

friend.lendCar.apply(me, [false]);

console.log(me.gotCar()); // false
```

These methods are very useful for giving objects temporary functionality.

Comment: To people that want to know how to see `console.log` check out: [What is console.log and how do I use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743730/what-is-console-log-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 27):

Another example with Call, Apply and Bind.
The difference between Call and Apply is evident, but **Bind** works like this:

1. Bind returns an instance of a function that can be executed
2. First Parameter is '*this*'
3. Second parameter is a *Comma separated* list of arguments (like *Call*)

}

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name; 
}
Person.prototype.getName = function(a,b) { 
     return this.name + " " + a + " " + b; 
}

var reader = new Person('John Smith');

reader.getName = function() {
   // Apply and Call executes the function and returns value

   // Also notice the different ways of extracting 'getName' prototype
   var baseName = Object.getPrototypeOf(this).getName.apply(this,["is a", "boy"]);
   console.log("Apply: " + baseName);

   var baseName = Object.getPrototypeOf(reader).getName.call(this, "is a", "boy"); 
   console.log("Call: " + baseName);

   // Bind returns function which can be invoked
   var baseName = Person.prototype.getName.bind(this, "is a", "boy"); 
   console.log("Bind: " + baseName());
}

reader.getName();
/* Output
Apply: John Smith is a boy
Call: John Smith is a boy
Bind: John Smith is a boy
*/
```

Answer (score 24):

I'd like to show an example, where the 'valueForThis' argument is used:

```
Array.prototype.push = function(element) {
   /*
   Native code*, that uses 'this'       
   this.put(element);
   */
}
var array = [];
array.push(1);
array.push.apply(array,[2,3]);
Array.prototype.push.apply(array,[4,5]);
array.push.call(array,6,7);
Array.prototype.push.call(array,8,9);
//[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**details: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.7*

Answer (score 24):

Call() takes comma-separated arguments, ex:

`.call(scope, arg1, arg2, arg3)`

and apply() takes an array of arguments, ex:

`.apply(scope, [arg1, arg2, arg3])`

here are few more usage examples: 
http://blog.i-evaluation.com/2012/08/15/javascript-call-and-apply/

Comment: `
// call() === comma-separated arguments (arguments-list)  

.call(this, args1, args2, args3, ...)

// apply() === array of arguments (array-items)  

.apply(this, [arr0, arr1, arr2, ...]) 
`

Answer (score 20):

From [**the MDN docs on Function.prototype.apply()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) :

> The apply() method calls a function with a given `this` value and
>   arguments provided as an array (or an array-like object).
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
> ```

From [**the MDN docs on Function.prototype.call()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) :

> The call() method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.
>
> #### Syntax
>
> ```
> fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
> ```

From [**Function.apply and Function.call in JavaScript**](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2007/07/04/function-apply-and-function-call-in-javascript.aspx) :

> The apply() method is identical to call(), except apply() requires an
>   array as the second parameter. The array represents the arguments for
>   the target method.

---

#### Code example :

```js
var doSomething = function() {
    var arr = [];
    for(i in arguments) {
        if(typeof this[arguments[i]] !== 'undefined') {
            arr.push(this[arguments[i]]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

var output = function(position, obj) {
    document.body.innerHTML += '<h3>output ' + position + '</h3>' + JSON.stringify(obj) + '\n<br>\n<br><hr>';
}

output(1, doSomething(
    'one',
    'two',
    'two',
    'one'
));

output(2, doSomething.apply({one : 'Steven', two : 'Jane'}, [
    'one',
    'two',
    'two',
    'one'
]));

output(3, doSomething.call({one : 'Steven', two : 'Jane'},
    'one',
    'two',
    'two',
    'one'
));
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/k7y5o0d6/9/).

Answer (score 13):

Here's a small-ish post, I wrote on this:

http://sizeableidea.com/call-versus-apply-javascript/

```
var obj1 = { which : "obj1" },
obj2 = { which : "obj2" };

function execute(arg1, arg2){
    console.log(this.which, arg1, arg2);
}

//using call
execute.call(obj1, "dan", "stanhope");
//output: obj1 dan stanhope

//using apply
execute.apply(obj2, ["dan", "stanhope"]);
//output: obj2 dan stanhope

//using old school
execute("dan", "stanhope");
//output: undefined "dan" "stanhope"
```

Comment: here is another one: http://blog.i-evaluation.com/2012/08/15/javascript-call-and-apply/

but basically it is right:

    .call(scope, arg1, arg2, arg3)

Answer (score 13):

Fundamental difference is that `call()` accepts an ***argument list***, while `apply()` accepts a ***single array of arguments***.

Comment: source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 9):

The difference is that `call()` takes the function arguments separately, and `apply()` takes the function arguments in an array.

Answer (score 8):

### Summary:

Both `call()` and `apply()` are methods which are located on `Function.prototype`. Therefore they are available on every function object via the prototype chain. Both `call()` and `apply()` can execute a function with a specified value of the `this`.

The main difference between `call()` and `apply()` is the way you have to pass in arguments into it. In both `call()` and `apply()` you pass as a first argument the object you want to be the value as `this`. The other arguments differ in the following way:

- With `call()` you have to put in the arguments normally (starting from the second argument)
- With `apply()` you have to pass in array of arguments.

### Example:

```js
let obj = {
  val1: 5,
  val2: 10
}

const summation = function (val3, val4) {
  return  this.val1 + this.val2 + val3 + val4;
}

console.log(summation.apply(obj, [2 ,3]));
// first we assign we value of this in the first arg
// with apply we have to pass in an array


console.log(summation.call(obj, 2, 3));
// with call we can pass in each arg individually
```

### Why would I need to use these functions?

The `this` value can be tricky sometimes in javascript. The value of `this` determined **when a function is executed not when a function is defined.** If our function is dependend on a right `this` binding we can use `call()` and `apply()` to enforce this behaviour. For example:

```js
var name = 'unwantedGlobalName';

const obj =  {
  name: 'Willem',
  sayName () { console.log(this.name);}
}


let copiedMethod = obj.sayName;
// we store the function in the copiedmethod variable



copiedMethod();
// this is now window, unwantedGlobalName gets logged

copiedMethod.call(obj);
// we enforce this to be obj, Willem gets logged
```

Answer (score 7):

We can differentiate call and apply methods as below

CALL : A function with argument provide individually.
If you know the arguments to be passed or there are no argument to pass you can use call.

APPLY : Call a function with argument provided as an array. You can use apply if you don't know how many argument are going to pass to the function.

There is a advantage of using apply over call, we don't need to change the number of argument only we can change a array that is passed.

There is not big difference in performance. But we can say call is bit faster as compare to apply because an array need to evaluate in apply method.

Answer (score 7):

The main difference is, using call, we can change the scope and pass arguments as normal, but apply lets you call it using arguments as an Array (pass them as an array). But in terms of what they to do in your code, they are pretty similar.

> While the syntax of this function is almost identical to that of
>   apply(), the fundamental difference is that call() accepts an argument
>   list, while apply() accepts a single array of arguments.

So as you see, there is not a big difference, but still, there are cases we prefer using call() or apply(). For example, look at the code below, which finding the smallest and largest number in an array from MDN, using the apply method:

```
// min/max number in an array
var numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];

// using Math.min/Math.max apply
var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); 
// This about equal to Math.max(numbers[0], ...)
// or Math.max(5, 6, ...)

var min = Math.min.apply(null, numbers)
```

So the main difference is just the way we passing the arguments:
 
 
**Call:**

```
function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...);
```

**Apply:**

```
function.apply(thisArg, [argsArray]);
```

Answer (score 7):

I just want to add a simple example to a well explained [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986909/9224597) by [flatline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20846/flatline), which makes it easy to understand for beginners.

```
func.call(context, args1, args2 );   // pass arguments as "," separated value

func.apply(context, [args1, args2]); // pass arguments as "Array"
```

we also use "Call" and "Apply" method for changing  **reference** as defined in code below

```js
let Emp1 = {
  name: 'X',
  getEmpDetail: function(age, department) {
    console.log(`Name: ${this.name}    Age: ${age}    Department: ${department}`)
  }
}

Emp1.getEmpDetail(23, 'Delivery')

// 1st approach of changing "this"
let Emp2 = {
  name: 'Y',
  getEmpDetail: Emp1.getEmpDetail
}

Emp2.getEmpDetail(55, 'Finance')

// 2nd approach of changing "this" using "Call" and "Apply"
let Emp3 = {
  name: 'Emp3_Object',
}

Emp1.getEmpDetail.call(Emp3, 30, 'Admin')

// here we have change the ref from **Emp1 to Emp3**  object
// now this will print "Name =  Emp3_Object" because it is pointing to Emp3 object
Emp1.getEmpDetail.apply(Emp3, [30, 'Admin'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Difference between these to methods are, how you want to pass the parameters.

“A for array and C for comma” is a handy mnemonic.

Comment: What does this answer provide that is not already well-provided in other answers?

Answer (score 5):

Call and apply both are used to force the `this` value when a function is executed. The only difference is that `call` takes `n+1` arguments where 1 is `this` and `'n' arguments`. `apply` takes only two arguments, one is `this` the other is argument array.

The advantage I see in `apply` over `call` is that we can easily delegate a function call to other function without much effort;

```
function sayHello() {
  console.log(this, arguments);
}

function hello() {
  sayHello.apply(this, arguments);
}

var obj = {name: 'my name'}
hello.call(obj, 'some', 'arguments');
```

Observe how easily we delegated `hello` to `sayHello` using `apply`, but with `call` this is very difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add a little detail to this.

these two calls are almost equivalent:

```
func.call(context, ...args); // pass an array as list with spread operator

func.apply(context, args);   // is same as using apply
```

There’s only a minor difference:

> - The `spread` operator ... allows passing ***iterable*** `args` as the list to call.
> - The `apply` accepts only ***array-like*** args.

So, these calls complement each other. Where we expect an *iterable*, `call` works, where we expect an *array-like*, `apply` works.

And for objects that are both *iterable* and *array-like*, like a real array, we technically could use any of them, but ***apply*** will probably be **faster** because most JavaScript engines internally optimize it better.

Answer (score 4):

Even though `call` and `apply` achive the same thing, I think there is atleast one place where you cannot use `call` but can only use `apply`. That is when you want to support inheritance and want to call the constructor.

Here is a function allows you to create classes which also supports creating classes by extending other classes.

```
function makeClass( properties ) {
    var ctor = properties['constructor'] || function(){}
    var Super = properties['extends'];
    var Class = function () {
                 // Here 'call' cannot work, only 'apply' can!!!
                 if(Super)
                    Super.apply(this,arguments);  
                 ctor.apply(this,arguments);
                }
     if(Super){
        Class.prototype = Object.create( Super.prototype );
        Class.prototype.constructor = Class;
     }
     Object.keys(properties).forEach( function(prop) {
           if(prop!=='constructor' && prop!=='extends')
            Class.prototype[prop] = properties[prop];
     });
   return Class; 
}

//Usage
var Car = makeClass({
             constructor: function(name){
                         this.name=name;
                        },
             yourName: function() {
                     return this.name;
                   }
          });
//We have a Car class now
 var carInstance=new Car('Fiat');
carInstance.youName();// ReturnsFiat

var SuperCar = makeClass({
               constructor: function(ignore,power){
                     this.power=power;
                  },
               extends:Car,
               yourPower: function() {
                    return this.power;
                  }
              });
//We have a SuperCar class now, which is subclass of Car
var superCar=new SuperCar('BMW xy',2.6);
superCar.yourName();//Returns BMW xy
superCar.yourPower();// Returns 2.6
```

Comment: I believe call would work there with the spread operator as described in the selected answer. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3):

The `call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and a second parameter which are **arguments separated by comma**

```
object.someMethod.call( someObject, arguments )
```

The `apply()` method is the same as call except the fact that the second argument it takes is an **array of arguments**

```
object.someMethod.apply( someObject, arrayOfarguments )
```

```js
var car  = {  
  name: "Reno",
  country: "France",
  showBuyer: function(firstName, lastName) {
    console.log(`${firstName} ${lastName} just bought a ${this.name} from ${this.country}`);
  }
}

const firstName = "Bryan";
const lastName = "Smith";

car.showBuyer(firstName, lastName);  // Bryan just bought a Reno from France

const obj = { name: "Maserati", country: "Italy" };

car.showBuyer.call(obj, firstName, lastName); // Bryan Smith just bought a Maserati from Italy

car.showBuyer.apply(obj, [firstName, lastName]); // Bryan Smith just bought a Maserati from Italy
```

Answer (score 1):

In the apply() method, arguments are called in the form of an array, while in the call() method, arguments are passed individually as separate parameters

Regarding performance, call is a little it faster than the apply() method, because of abasence of array-arguments in this method.

Use the apply() method, when you are having array-like object or actual array.
Use the call() method, when you know the exact number of arguments, you want to pass to the function.