# please explain the apply and call methods in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

What is the main difference between apply and call methods...
I go through the web but unable to find the best solution..
Please help me friends...

Comment: There is no *best* solution ;)

Comment: @Felix: +1, it didn't occur to me that this would probably be a dupe.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Oops, didn't notice that one ;)

Comment: @Andy E, @elusive: No worries guys, I answered enough duplicate questions myself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every function in JavaScript receives two objects in addition to the default parameters. These are `this` and `arguments`. The value of `this` is determined by it's invocation pattern. `apply` or `call` can be used to invoke a function and provide it a default `this` object.

This will be very useful in many situations. For example, `arguments` is an array-like object, but not really an `Array` with all the useful Array methods. So, to apply an Array method `slice` on `arguments`, you can do this:

```
Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, [1, 2])
```

Had `arguments` been an object of `Array` type, you could have used

```
arguments.slice(1, 2)
```

`call` is nothing but a modified version of apply. See elusive's comment.

Mr.Douglus Crockford gives a very good introduction to JavaScript functions in this video: [Function the Ultimate](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=crockonjs-3).

Comment: What relevance does the stuff about `arguments` have?

Comment: OP has been asking questions about JavaScript for quite some time. I assumed that he was getting started with JS. I thought a proper introduction to function invocation pattern would be useful to him. :)

Answer (score 4):

The main difference is that `call` accepts a list of arguments, where arguments after the first one are passed directly to the method:

```
myFunc.call(thisObj, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Whereas `apply` accepts only two arguments - the first is the `this` object and the second is an array of arguments to pass to the method:

```
myFunc.apply(thisObj, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
```

`apply` is often used in a situation where you want to pass the `arguments` object, which contains a list of arguments passed to the current function, to another method:

```
function myOtherFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    if (typeof arg1 == "object" && arg1 !== null)
        myFunc.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thank you and nice to hear.. but can we use any method at any situation or is there any limitations to these mehtods..

Comment: @Mihir: `apply` can be used in place of `call` pretty much anywhere you can think of.  However, `call` isn't a great replacement for `apply` because it's not as dynamic.  I've updated my answer to give you an example use of `apply`.

Comment: @Mihir: `call` is just syntactic sugar for `apply`. Makes it easier to call functions with just one parameter.

Answer (score 3):

`.apply()` and `.call()` are very similar. The only difference is how they pass arguments to the called function. `.apply()` takes an array of  arguments, while `.call()` can be used like a regular function call:

```
someFunction.apply(context, [argument1, argument2]);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
someFunction.call(context, argument1, argument2);
```

Comment: Thank you and nice to hear.. but can we use any method at any situation or is there any limitations to these mehtods..

Comment: @Mihir: Both methods are members of the function object prototype. Both can be used on any function.