# Using scope.$watch to observe when a function executes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Suppose I have a custom directive, named `my-directive`, that has the default scope settings (`scope: false`, which means it shares the scope of the (parent) controller enclosing the directive), and I have a function `my_function`, attached to the controller's scope. I wonder if in the custom directive's link function if I can use `scope.$watch` to observe when `my_function` executes?

Here's a code for illustration:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <my-directive></my-directive>

</div>
```

the controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.my_function = function() {
    ...
    }

});
```

the custom directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        [scope: false,]
        ...
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            // can I scope.$watch my_function here to check when it executes?

        }
    }
});
```

Update:

Here's my reason for asking this:
When `my_function` (which essentially is a retrieve function through `$http.get`) executes, it should update an object, say `my_data`. If I try to `scope.$watch` `my_data`, there may be a situation where `my_function` executes and there is no change in `my_data` (such as when I edit an entry in `my_data` and decides to cancel the update anyway), thus a portion of the code that I want to execute in link function is not executed. So I want to make sure my code in link function executes whenever `my_function` executes, whether or not there is a change `my_data`.

Comment: What's the use case for invoking `my_function`?

Comment: @gustavohenke check my update above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to solve your problem that I could think of.

#### 1. Use a counter

You can always increment a counter when invoking `my_function`:

```
// This will reside in your controller
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.my_function = function () {
  // do your logic
  $scope.counter++;
};

// This will reside in your directive
$scope.$watch( "counter", function () {
  // do something
});
```

#### 2. Simply watch `my_data`

Assuming `my_function` will *always* override the `my_data` variable, you can use the default Angular behavior for `$watch`. You don't have to care if your backend has news for you or not, the reference will never be the same.

```
// in your controller
$scope.my_function = function () {
  $http.get(...).then(function ( response ) {
    $scope.my_data = response.data;
  });
};

// in your directive
$scope.$watch( "my_data", function () {
  // do something
});
```

Obviously, this is the cleaner way to do this, but you may get in trouble if you don't unit test because of one of the following:

- You add any sort of logic around `my_data` that may conflict with your watcher;
- You want to cache your HTTP calls.

---

I hope I was able to help you! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't tried the first one, but the second one worked.So does this mean, `scope.$watch` checks for both changes in object reference and actual value?

Comment: Nope, by default is just object reference. You can check for value equality by passing [another `true` argument to `$scope.$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to do, you may not need `$watch` at all.

If the function isn't ever going to change, you can just make a dummy wrapper.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        var oldFunc = scope.my_function;
        scope.my_function = function(sameArgs){
            //method_was_called();
            if(oldFunc){oldFunc(sameArgs);}
        }

    }
```

Then you can do whatever logic you want inside your wrapper function, either before or after you run the 'super' method.

Check also
[Javascript: Extend a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578424/javascript-extend-a-function)