# How can I extend Backbone.history.navigate?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

When I call Backbone.history.navigate, I want to be able to change a global variable.

I want to set

```
window.linkclicked = true; // when someone clicks a link
```

and

```
window.linkclicked = false; // when back button is pushed.
```

Is there a way to do this using javascript prototypes?
How do I insert that logic inside the "navigate" method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Extend a Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578424/javascript-extend-a-function)

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `Backbone.history` instance and just redefine the [`navigate`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-236) function as you wish.

```
var originalNavigate = Backbone.history.navigate;

_.extend(Backbone.history, {
    navigate: function(fragment, options) {
        // do stuff before
        var returnValue = originalNavigate.apply(this, arguments);
        // do stuff after
        return returnValue;
    },
});
```

Or with the closure module pattern:

```
Backbone.history.navigate = (function(navigate) {
    return function(fragment, options) {
        /* ...snip ...*/
    }
})(Backbone.history.navigate);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extend the functionality with underscore:

```
_.extend(Backbone.history.navigate, {
linkClicked : function( bool ){
//handle link clicked
}
});
```

You can call this with:

```
Backbone.history.navigate.linkClicked( true ); 
//or
Backbone.history.navigate.linkClicked( false );
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking how to make it so that calling `Backbone.history.navigate` also changes a global variable, not for a separate function on `Backbone.history.navigate`.

Comment: Well, I guess I could have a wrapper.