# Change function behavior without proxy

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

I can do something like this:

```
var foo = ...// some function assignment
var fooString = foo.toString()
...
// add some alert to foo
...
var fooWithAlert = new Function(forStringWithAlert)
```

Is there a way to mutate first `foo` instead of creating new function?
I need it to monkey patch some dependency without recreating whole hierarchy of objects.

I need to patch a constructor function in a library, just add an alert on every call. But without juggling with prototypes

Comment: you can manipulate the string by adding the alert function and then appending this manipulated string into a head tag, Not sure with other solutions.

Comment: It's good to simplify things, but I think you've gone so far simplifying this question that you've probably omitted details relevant to the answers. What, specifically, do you need to do to the function `foo` refers to? Can you come up with a simple, but *representative*, thing you need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Extend a Function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578424/javascript-extend-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't *modify* the function `foo` refers to. You can only make `foo` refer to a new function that does what you want. One way to do that is to use your `toString` approach, but it's best to avoid that if at all possible, because the function you get as a result will not be the same as the original; the scope it has access to will be different.

Usually, you do want a proxy/wrapper, e.g.:

```js
// The original foo
var foo = function(arg) {
    return "original foo says '" + arg + "'";
};
console.log(foo("bar"));

// Let's wrap it
(function() {
    var originalFoo = foo;
    foo = function() {
        return originalFoo.apply(this, arguments) + " plus updated foo";
    };
})();
console.log(foo("bar"));
```

This doesn't create a hierarchy of objects or similar, it just wraps `foo`.

If `foo` is a *constructor function* (let's call it `Foo`), you'll also want to copy `Foo.prototype`:

```js
// The original Foo
var Foo = function(arg) {
    this.value = "original foo";
    this.arg = arg;
};
Foo.prototype.getArg = function() {
    return this.arg;
};
var f1 = new Foo("bar");
console.log(f1.getArg());

// Let's wrap it
(function() {
    var originalFoo = Foo;
    Foo = function() {
        var rv = originalFoo.apply(this, arguments);
        this.arg += " (plus more from augmented foo)";
        return rv;
    };
    Foo.prototype = originalFoo.prototype;
})();
var f2 = new Foo("bar");
console.log(f2.getArg());
```

And of course, if you need to wrap a function on `Foo.prototype`, you can do it just like `foo` in my first example:

```js
// The original Foo
var Foo = function(arg) {
    this.value = "original foo";
    this.arg = arg;
};
Foo.prototype.getArg = function() {
    return this.arg;
};
var f = new Foo("bar");
console.log(f.getArg());

// Let's wrap its getArg
(function() {
    var originalGetArg = Foo.prototype.getArg;
    Foo.prototype.getArg = function() {
        return originalGetArg.apply(this, arguments) + " updated";
    };
})();
console.log(f.getArg());
```

Note how it doesn't matter that we wrapped the prototype function *after* creating the `f` object.

Comment: better perhaps to encapsulate the `originalFoo` in an IIFE ?

Comment: what if he wants to add some 20 lines of code logic into it? Can it still be achieved by this method?

Comment: I guess i need to be more concrete https://github.com/Jxck/assert/blob/master/assert.js#L190

What happens with `foo` prototype in the case?

Comment: @Reddy: Yes, the quantity doesn't matter, just the location. Wrappers work for doing things before the original, or after, or both, but not *in the middle*.

Comment: @Alnitak: I wasn't expecting the OP to use the code verbatim, I was expecting some common sense. :-)

Comment: @kharandziuk: The details related to your question must be **in** your question, not just linked.

Comment: @kharandziuk: I've updated the answer to include a note about constructor functions, and functions on a constructor's `prototype` object.

Comment: one minor gotcha (discovered whilst playing with a similar system) is that the replaced function won't have the same arity as the original.  I don't know if it's allowable to just say `Foo.length = originalFoo.length`

Comment: @Alnitak: *"the replaced function won't have the same arity as the original"* Good point! *"I don't know if it's allowable to just say `Foo.length = originalFoo.length`"* No, `length` on functions is read-only [according to the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-instances-length). It's rare, of course, for anything to actually check the arity of the function, but it's a good point nonetheless. If I needed it, I'd probably just have branch and create the arity I needed (up to, say, 10 and using `new Function` beyond that)...

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and discovered that `f.length` is indeed read-only.  I have seen code recently that checks the arity of a passed function, but I don't recall what it was.