# How to avoid doing inheritance

Tags: javascript

I have an object called `a` that I use nearly all the time.

Then 'b' comes along being awkward and I need to do some other things before calling notify.

What is the best functional/prototypical approach to take get the same thing has called the parent in object-oriented (Which I understand to not be possible without using Javascript classes - correct me if I'm wrong)

```
let a = {};

a.notify = () => {
    doSomethingCool();
}

var b = Object.create(a);

b.notify = () => {
    doCoolStuffFirst();
    doSomethingCool();
}
```

Comment: Could you give us a [mcve] ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: Extend a Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578424/javascript-extend-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you're asking. Are you simply looking for

```
const notify_orig = b.notify;
b.notify = () => {
    doCoolStuffFirst();
    notify_orig.call(b);
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it is easy with classes:

```
class A {
  notify() {
    doSomethingCool();
  }
}

class B {
  notify() {
    doCoolStuffFirst();
    super.notify();
  }
}
```

Without ES6 classes, you're in for a rough ride. ES6 compiler translates `super.notify()` into something like

```
_get(
   B.prototype.__proto__ ||
   Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype),
   "notify", this
).call(this);
```

(with `_get` being a kind-of-huge utility method to smooth the rough edges about different kinds of values and inheritance and stuff). It's not *impossible*, it's just complicated enough that you probably don't want to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `__proto__` or `class` (which is syntactic sugar in ES6).

```js
function doSomethingCool() {
    console.log("something cool");
}

function doCoolStuffFirst() {
    console.log("cool stuff first");
}

let a = {};
a.notify = () => {
    doSomethingCool();
}
a.notify();

let b = Object.create(a)
b.notify = (() => {
    let notifySuper = b.notify; // reference to the 'super' method
    return () => {
        doCoolStuffFirst();
        notifySuper();
    }
})();
b.notify();
```