# How to emulate what AngularJs decorators are doing in vanilla Javascript (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-class

AngularJs Decorators Provides an effective way to extend functions in services without affecting the original service. 
How does one emulate this behavior with javascript classes?

I have 2 libraries. One containing common logic and UI elements and another more specific to the page I am building. I have to extend the class written in the library containing the core logic in my specific one and then use the extended version's functions from the core library. I do understand this might seem like a faulty design, but the same could be achieved with decorators in AngularJS.However, I am using plain ES6 Classes. So how do I go about it?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578424/javascript-extend-a-function this help ? Try reading about decorator design pattern in JS

Comment: I don't think ES decorators solves the problem.

Comment: provide some code of what you want to achieve, i'll try to make it

Answer (score 0):

Rather silly example:

```
class A {foo() {console.log(1)}}
var a  = new A();
// super decorate
var t  = a.foo; a.foo = () => { console.log(2); t()}
// awesome result:
a.foo()
>> 2
>> 1
```