# JQuery callback function flow

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am very new in jquery. so i was searching google for jquery callback function and i got a code but i did not understand the flow of the code. so please anyone help me to understand the coding flow.

here is the code

```
function mightyplugin(foo, callback){
// big code block here

   callback.apply(this, [foo]);
}

mightyplugin("Bar!", function(param){
    alert(param);
});
```

here i am passing `"Bar!"` as one argument to function `mightyplugin` and a anonymous function.

1. what `callback.apply` does. what `this` keyword will hold actually.... why it is required.
2. why `[foo]` is passed as array.
3. what would be the syntax if i pass many argument like

   ```
   mightyplugin("Bar!","1stone","2ndone", function(param){
       alert(param);
   });
   ```

i know callback function invoke when first function finish but here situation is different... why?

please explain...
thanks

Comment: What are you trying to apply the callback to?

Comment: i just need to understand the jquery callback technique for knowledge only.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't see that you were writing the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this isn't jquery.  This is an example of how to deal with callback functions yourself, independent of jquery.

To answer your qestions:

1. Details on `apply` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply
2. As you'll see if you read the above link, the 2nd parameter passed to `apply` is an array of arguments.
3. I'm not sure what your intent is for those other parameters, but you can simply add more parameters to your function:

---

```
function mightyplugin(foo, foo1, foo2, callback){
   // big code block here

   callback.apply(this, [foo, foo1, foo2]);
}

mightyplugin("Bar!","1stone","2ndone", function(param){ alert(param); });
```

Comment: some time i saw callback function is invoke like callback.call(this, [foo, foo1, foo2]); instead of callback.apply(this, [foo, foo1, foo2]);
.so i need to know what is the difference between apply & call. when to use call() and when to use apply(). plzz put some focus. thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply

Answer (score 1):

1. `this` is the current function context, in your situation mightyplugin
2. `foo` is passed as an array because apply needs an array as argument
3. `mightyplugin([1,2,3,4], function(){...});`
   and then `callback.apply(this, foo)`

You can read more on the Mozilla Developer Network on [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and it's brother [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)