# Super in Backbone

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js

When I override the `clone()` method of a `Backbone.Model`, is there a way to call this overriden method from my implantation? Something like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    clone: function(){
        super.clone();//calling the original clone method
    }
})
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You'll want to use:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.clone.call(this);
```

This will call the original `clone()` method from `Backbone.Model` with the context of `this`(The current model).

From [Backbone docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend):

> Brief aside on super: JavaScript does not provide a simple way to call
>   super — the function of the same name defined higher on the prototype
>   chain. If you override a core function like set, or save, and you want
>   to invoke the parent object's implementation, you'll have to
>   explicitly call it.

```
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
 set: function(attributes, options) {
 Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
 ...
 }    
});
```

Comment: Backbone docs seems to suggest e.g. Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments); what is the difference between using prototype.func_name.apply(...) and prototype.func_name.call(...) ?

Comment: @MikaelLepistö see the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply

Comment: This wont work with the full prototype chain. If the direct super class' prototype doesn't contain the method, there'll be an exception.

Answer (score 36):

You can also use the [`__super__`](http://blog.usefunnel.com/2011/03/js-inheritance-with-backbone/) property which is a reference to the parent class prototype:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  clone: function(){
    MyModel.__super__.clone.call(this);
  }
});
```

Comment: Just a little background on this answer: `__super__` is a reference to the parent's prototype that Backbone framework makes every time a Backbone model, collection, router, or view is extended. While it's not a standard property it does work cross-browser since its framework generated. However, even the Backbone official docs don't mention this and say to use `Backbone.Model.prototype.set.call(this, attributes, options);` method. Both seem to work fine, though.

Comment: @MauvisLedford Is your example code correct or should the `.set.` be `.clone.` for the OP's use case?

Comment: Mine was just a non-related example.  It would be `Backbone.Model.prototype.clone.call(this, attributes, options);` in his case.

Comment: You could also use: this.constructor.__super__

Comment: @JasonM nope, `this.constructor` is not guaranteed to be `MyModel` and it would make a stack overflow if `MyModel` was used as a parent class.

Answer (score 18):

Josh Nielsen [found an elegant solution for this](http://forrst.com/posts/Backbone_js_super_function-4co), which hides a lot of the ugliness.

Just add this snippet to your app to extend Backbone's model:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype._super = function(funcName){
    return this.constructor.prototype[funcName].apply(this, _.rest(arguments));
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
Model = Backbone.model.extend({
    set: function(arg){
        // your code here

        // call the super class function
        this._super('set', arg);
    }
});
```

Comment: this only works when there is only one level of implementation A.foo -> B.foo, in the case of A.foo -> B.foo -> C.foo you will get a stack overflow due to B's this refering to itself

Comment: My answer below fixes the problem of having more than one level of inheritance,

Answer (score 4):

Working from the answers given by geek_dave and charlysisto, I wrote this to add `this._super(funcName, ...)` support in classes that have multiple levels of inheritance. It's worked well in my code.

```
Backbone.View.prototype._super = Backbone.Model.prototype._super = function(funcName) {
        // Find the scope of the caller.
        var scope = null;
        var scan = this.__proto__;
        search: while (scope == null && scan != null) {
            var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(scan);
            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                if (scan[names[i]] === arguments.callee.caller) {
                    scope = scan;
                    break search;
                }
            }
            scan = scan.constructor.__super__;
        }
        return scan.constructor.__super__[funcName].apply(this, _.rest(arguments));
    };
```

A year later I've fixed some bugs and made things faster. Below is the code that I use now.

```
var superCache = {};

// Hack "super" functionality into backbone. 
Backbone.View.prototype._superFn = Backbone.Model.prototype._superFn = function(funcName, _caller) {
    var caller = _caller == null ? arguments.callee.caller : _caller;
    // Find the scope of the caller.
    var scope = null;
    var scan = this.__proto__;
    var className = scan.constructor.className;
    if (className != null) {
        var result = superCache[className + ":" + funcName];
        if (result != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if (result[i].caller === caller) {
                    return result[i].fn;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    search: while (scope == null && scan != null) {
        var names = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(scan);
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            if (scan[names[i]] === caller) {
                scope = scan;
                break search;
            }
        }
        scan = scan.constructor.__super__;
    }
    var result = scan.constructor.__super__[funcName];
    if (className != null) {
        var entry = superCache[className + ":" + funcName];
        if (entry == null) {
            entry = [];
            superCache[className + ":" + funcName] = entry;
        }
        entry.push({
                caller: caller,
                fn: result
            });
    }
    return result;
};

Backbone.View.prototype._super = Backbone.Model.prototype._super = function(funcName) {
        var args = new Array(arguments.length - 1);
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            args[i] = arguments[i + 1];
        }
        return this._superFn(funcName, arguments.callee.caller).apply(this, args);
    };
```

Then given this code:

```
var A = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
 //   className: "A",
    go1: function() { console.log("A1"); },  
    go2: function() { console.log("A2"); },  
    });

var B = A.extend({ 
 //   className: "B",
    go2: function() { this._super("go2"); console.log("B2"); },  
    });

var C = B.extend({ 
 //   className: "C",
    go1: function() { this._super("go1"); console.log("C1"); },
    go2: function() { this._super("go2"); console.log("C2"); }  
    });

var c = new C();
c.go1();
c.go2();
```

The output in the console is this:

```
A1
C1
A2
B2
C2
```

What's interesting is that class C's call to `this._super("go1")` scans the class hierarchy until it gets a hit in class A. Other solutions do not do this.

P.S. Uncomment the `className` entries of the class definitions to enable caching of the `_super` lookup. (The assumption is that these class names will be unique in the application.)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once. First sensible description of super I've found on the internet. This concept always confused me, it's quite otherworldly from standard JavaScript...

Answer (score 3):

If you want just to call  this._super();  without passing the function name as an argument

```
Backbone.Controller.prototype._super = function(){
    var fn = Backbone.Controller.prototype._super.caller, funcName;

    $.each(this, function (propName, prop) {
        if (prop == fn) {
            funcName = propName;
        }
    });

    return this.constructor.__super__[funcName].apply(this, _.rest(arguments));
}
```

Better use this plugin: 
https://github.com/lukasolson/Backbone-Super

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can cache the original method (although not tested):

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  origclone: Backbone.Model.clone,
  clone: function(){
    origclone();//calling the original clone method
  }
});
```

Comment: It should be `Backbone.Model.prototype.clone` and `this.origclone()`. It's equivalent to `Backbone.Model.prototype.clone.call(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

backbone._super.js, from my gists: https://gist.github.com/sarink/a3cf3f08c17691395edf

```
// Forked/modified from: https://gist.github.com/maxbrunsfeld/1542120
// This method gives you an easier way of calling super when you're using Backbone in plain javascript.
// It lets you avoid writing the constructor's name multiple times.
// You still have to specify the name of the method.
//
// So, instead of having to write:
//
//    var Animal = Backbone.Model.extend({
//        word: "",
//        say: function() {
//            return "I say " + this.word;
//        }
//    });
//    var Cow = Animal.extend({
//        word: "moo",
//        say: function() {
//            return Animal.prototype.say.apply(this, arguments) + "!!!"
//        }
//    });
//
//
// You get to write:
//
//    var Animal = Backbone.Model.extend({
//        word: "",
//        say: function() {
//            return "I say " + this.word;
//        }
//    });
//    var Cow = Animal.extend({
//        word: "moo",
//        say: function() {
//            return this._super("say", arguments) + "!!!"
//        }
//    });

(function(root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["underscore", "backbone"], function(_, Backbone) {
            return factory(_, Backbone);
        });
    }
    else if (typeof exports !== "undefined") {
        var _ = require("underscore");
        var Backbone = require("backbone");
        module.exports = factory(_, Backbone);
    }
    else {
        factory(root._, root.Backbone);
    }
}(this, function(_, Backbone) {
    "use strict";

    // Finds the next object up the prototype chain that has a different implementation of the method.
    var findSuper = function(methodName, childObject) {
        var object = childObject;
        while (object[methodName] === childObject[methodName]) {
            object = object.constructor.__super__;
        }
        return object;
    };

    var _super = function(methodName) {
        // Keep track of how far up the prototype chain we have traversed, in order to handle nested calls to `_super`.
        this.__superCallObjects__ || (this.__superCallObjects__ = {});
        var currentObject = this.__superCallObjects__[methodName] || this;
        var parentObject  = findSuper(methodName, currentObject);
        this.__superCallObjects__[methodName] = parentObject;

        // If `methodName` is a function, call it with `this` as the context and `args` as the arguments, if it's an object, simply return it.
        var args = _.tail(arguments);
        var result = (_.isFunction(parentObject[methodName])) ? parentObject[methodName].apply(this, args) : parentObject[methodName];
        delete this.__superCallObjects__[methodName];
        return result;
    };

    // Mix in to Backbone classes
    _.each(["Model", "Collection", "View", "Router"], function(klass) {
        Backbone[klass].prototype._super = _super;
    });

    return Backbone;
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you don't know what the parent class is exactly (multiple inheritance or you want a helper function) then you can use the following:

```
var ChildModel = ParentModel.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    this.__proto__.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    // Do child model initialization.
  }

});
```

With helper function:

```
function parent(instance) {
  return instance.__proto__.constructor.__super__;
};

var ChildModel = ParentModel.extend({

  initialize: function() {
    parent(this).initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    // Do child model initialization.
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parent class as an option during instantiation:

```
BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
        var self = this;
        this.myModel = new MyModel({parent: self});
    } 
});
```

Then in your MyModel you can call parent methods like this

this.options.parent.method();
Keep in mind this creates a retain cycle on the two objects. So to let the garbage collector do it's job you would need to manually destroy the retain on one of the objects when finished with it. If you're application is pretty large. I would encourage you to look more into hierarchal setups so events can travel up to the correct object.

Comment: That's not an inheritance example and not the same "parent" that is discussed in this thread. Also, the `var self = this` is unnecessary in this case since it's not inside a callback function losing the context.

Comment: Truth. I wrote this code when I was young and dumb. Thanks for the update here. Feel free to edit the post and update it. I don't write Backbone anymore, so I don't feel like I can confidently update it.

Comment: Editing it won't help since it's not answering the question at hand. I think the only option would be to remove the answer altogether.

Answer (score 0):

2 functions below, one requires you pass in the function name, the other can "discover" which function we want the super version of

```js
Discover.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
       _super:function(func) {
        var proto = this.constructor.__super__;
        if (_.isUndefined(proto[func])) {
            throw "Invalid super method: " + func + " does not exist in prototype chain.";
        }
        return proto[func].apply(this, _.rest(arguments));
    },
    _superElegant:function() {
        t = arguments;
        var proto = this.constructor.__super__;
        var name;
        for (name in this) {
            if (this[name] === arguments.callee.caller) {
                console.log("FOUND IT " + name);
                break;
            } else {
                console.log("NOT IT " + name);
            }
        }
        if (_.isUndefined(proto[name])) {
            throw "Super method for: " + name + " does not exist.";
        } else {
            console.log("Super method for: " + name + " does exist!");
        }
        return proto[name].apply(this, arguments);
    },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how I would do this:

```
ParentClassName.prototype.MethodToInvokeName.apply(this);
```

so for your example this is:

```
Model.prototype.clone.apply(this)
```