# Accessing parent class in Backbone

Tags: javascript, oop, class, inheritance, backbone.js

I need to call the `initialize` method of the parent class, from inside the inherited `MyModel`-class, instead of completely overwriting it as I am doing today.

How could I do this?

Here's what my code looks right now:

```
BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(attributes, options) {
        // Do parent stuff stuff
    }
});

MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        // Invoke BaseModel.initialize();
        // Continue doing specific stuff for this child-class.
    },
});
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        MyModel.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        // Continue doing specific stuff for this child-class.
    },
});
```

Comment: @Industrial then it's doing something silly. Try `this.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);`

Comment: `__ super __` is not intended to use it directly, as the underscored name implies.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko sure it is, it's just someone choose a `__super__` naming convention in their `inherits` utility function to avoid naming conflicts. It's exposed by backbone

Comment: @Raynos: Why not `BaseModel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);`? this should work without `__super__`.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko either works. The `__super__` solution is more elegant because it doesn't require changing when you rename `BaseModel`.

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend
Brief aside on super: JavaScript does not provide a simple way to call super — the function of the same name defined higher on the prototype chain. If you override a core function like set, or save, and you want to invoke the parent object's implementation, you'll have to explicitly call it...

Comment: In Ember.js <3 you just do `this._super()`. tada! it's magic. :)

Comment: @SalmanPK I'm sure that will break horribly in plenty of edgecases. It's impossible to implement a sensibly semantic `super` in JS.

Comment: FWIW Jeremy Ashkenas [**states**](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/787#issuecomment-3143358) that `__super__` is not intended to be used directly.

Answer (score 129):

Try

```
MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        BaseModel.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        // Continue doing specific stuff for this child-class.
    },
});
```

Comment: this appears to work even in the presence of `_.bindAll(this)` calls, which render the `__super__` property of the constructor undefined.

Comment: better than using `__super__` has the underscores suggests a private member

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me, when I was trying to inherit among my models:

```
MyModel.prototype.initialize.call(this, options);
```

Referenced from http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I think it'd be

```
MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.constructor.__super__.initialize.call(this);
        // Continue doing specific stuff for this child-class.
    },
});
```

Comment: It's `this.__super__.initialize.call(this);`

Comment: Both `this.__super__.prototype.initialize.call(this);` and `this.__super__.initialize.call(this);` throws `this.__super__ is undefined` in Firebug.

Comment: Try this.constructor.__super__.initialize.call(this);

Comment: I wanted to pass arguments to the initialize function, and this is the only version that worked for me
    this.constructor.__super__.initialize.call(this,arguments);

Comment: FWIW Jeremy Ashkenas [**states**](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/787#issuecomment-3143358) that `__super__` is not intended to be used directly.

Answer (score 4):

this seems to be almost a duplicate of [Super in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596861/super-in-backbone), so you want something like this:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.initialize.call(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @wheresrhys, but I would use apply instead of call in case BaseModel.initialize is expecting arguments.  I try to avoid processing the attributes map that can be passed to a Backbone Model upon initialization, but if the BaseModel were actually a View or a Collection then I might want to set options.

```
var MyModel = BaseModel.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        // Continue doing specific stuff for this child-class.
    },
});
```

Comment: FWIW Jeremy Ashkenas [**states**](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/787#issuecomment-3143358) that `__super__` is not intended to be used directly.

Answer (score 0):

here's a multi generation callSuper method, just add it to your extending class.

```
callSuper: function (methodName) {
    var previousSuperPrototype, fn, ret;

    if (this.currentSuperPrototype) {
        previousSuperPrototype = this.currentSuperPrototype;
        // Up we go
        this.currentSuperPrototype = this.currentSuperPrototype.constructor.__super__;
    } else {
        // First level, just to to the parent
        this.currentSuperPrototype = this.constructor.__super__;
        previousSuperPrototype = null;
    }

    fn = this.currentSuperPrototype[methodName];

    ret = (arguments.length > 1) ? fn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)) : fn.call(this);

    this.currentSuperPrototype = previousSuperPrototype;

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You might consider rewriting your code using functional inheritance.

```
var BackBone=function(){
    var that={};

    that.m1=function(){

   };
   return that;

};

var MyModel=function(){

 var that=BackBone();
 var original_m1=that.m1;

//overriding of m1
 that.m1=function(){
    //call original m1
 original_m1();
 //custom code for m1
  };
};
```

Comment: i doubt rewriting backbone is in order here :) we got to manage with the structure backbone gives us, and there are far better solutions than rewriting all this, like the __super__ is more than enough.