# How to test which class my Backbone collection extends in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, jasmine

I got a custom Backbone.Collection class in Coffeescript.

I named it (it is responsible for pagination):

```
class SI.PaginatedCollection extends Backbone.Collection
```

I want to write Jasmine spec which will test do I extends that particular class.

Sorry for my English, I now it is probably horrible. ;)

**PS** I can parse Javascript, but Coffeescript would be ideal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems like overkill to me to test this, but you could do something like this:

```
describe "SI.PaginatedCollection", ->

  beforeEach ->
    @collection = new SI.PaginatedCollection()

  it "is a subclass of Backbone.Collection", ->
    expect(@collection instanceof Backbone.Collection).toBeTruthy()
```

If you’re going to be checking `instanceof` a lot and/or you care about descriptive Jasmine output, it would be worth making a custom matcher so you could write this:

```
expect(@collection).toBeInstanceOf(Backbone.Collection)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Jasmine 2.0 you can use `jasmine.any()` matcher. E.g:

```
collection = new SI.PaginatedCollection();

expect(collection).toEqual(jasmine.any(Backbone.Collection));
```

as mentioned in [this blogpost](http://filimanjaro.com/2014/jasmine-test-objects-type/)

Comment: Way more convenient than creating a custom matcher. Somewhat confusing API though.

Answer (score 0):

There is not proper way to get the `super` reference, nor in JavaScript neither in Backbone, even using [the `__super__` Backbone method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8971058/316700) is not advisable by [the documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-extend).

I think the cleanest approach is manually *brand* your subclasses with a *pseudo-static* attribute like:

```
var SI.PaginatedCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  parent: "Backbone.Collection"
});
```

Any time you need to check an instance is from an specific parent just check the `myInstance.parent`.

Comment: I use CoffeeScript. I do that by: `class SI.Collections.Sentences extends SI.PaginatedCollection` and it works well.