# Backbone View inheritance - call parent leads to recursion

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a three Backbone View class inheritance:

```
var preventRecursion = 0;

var parentView = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    console.log('parentView');
  }
});

var nestedChildView = parentView.extend({

  initialize: function(){

    if (++preventRecursion == 5) {throw "Recursion"};

    console.log('nestedChildView');
    this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this);          
  }
});

var nestedNestedChildView = nestedChildView.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    console.log('nestedNestedChildView');
    this.constructor.__super__.initialize.apply(this);          
  }
});
```

When I try to create nestedNestedChildView:

```
var t = new nestedNestedChildView();
```

I get infinite recursion:
Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5mWP/2/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As stated in the doc on [Model.extend](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend),

> Brief aside on super: JavaScript does not provide a simple way to call
>   super — the function of the same name defined higher on the prototype
>   chain. If you override a core function like set, or save, and you want
>   to invoke the parent object's implementation, you'll have to
>   explicitly call it, along these lines:

In your class hierarchy, `this.constructor` always equals to the constructor of `nestedNestedChildView`, which means `this.constructor.__super__.initialize` will be `nestedChildView.initialize` and thus a loop. See http://jsfiddle.net/X5yBb/ for a test.

You could explicitly call the class __super__ (http://jsfiddle.net/X5yBb/1/)

```
var nestedChildView = parentView.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('nestedChildView');
    nestedChildView.__super__.initialize.apply(this);          
  }
});

var nestedNestedChildView = nestedChildView.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('nestedNestedChildView');
    nestedNestedChildView.__super__.initialize.apply(this);          
  }
});
```

or call the methods on the prototype chain if you prefer (http://jsfiddle.net/X5yBb/2/):

```
var nestedChildView = parentView.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('nestedChildView');
    parentView.prototype.initialize.apply(this);          
  }
});

var nestedNestedChildView = nestedChildView.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('nestedNestedChildView');
    nestedChildView.prototype.initialize.apply(this);          
  }
});
```

See [Accessing parent class in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970606/accessing-parent-class-in-backbone) and [Super in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596861/super-in-backbone) for further info on the subject.