# Backbone extended view, extend method

Tags: inheritance, methods, backbone.js, extend

How would I extend an extended view parent method not to override, keep parents method statements and add some custom code, here is the example case

```
var SomeView = View.extend({
  parentMethod: function() {
    //some parent code
  }
})


var MyView = SomeView.extend({
  parentMethod: function() {
     //keep parents statements and extend
  }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing parent class in Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970606/accessing-parent-class-in-backbone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JavaScript does not provide a simple way to call super — the function
>   of the same name defined higher on the prototype chain. If you
>   override a core function like set, or save, and you want to invoke the
>   parent object's implementation, you'll have to explicitly call it

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend

```
   var MyView = SomeView.extend({
      parentMethod: function() {
         SomeView.prototype.parentMethod.apply(this, arguments);
         //some additional logic
      }
    })
```