# Backbone Collection inheritance, two constructors

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am looking for a way to have a BaseCollection for all my collections for shared behavior.

I was able to successfully do it with shared functions, but I want some initialization logic to occur in the BaseCollection so that all my collections trigger an event 'model-change'. Is there a way for my BaseCollection to have a constructor - is the code below the best way to do it? I assume if I put two initialize functions or two constructor override functions then only one will get called. So it seems I can only use one of them each.

```
  var BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

          constructor: function () {

                var self = this;
                this.on('change',function(model,property){
                    self.trigger('model-change',model,property);
                });
              Backbone.Collection.apply(this, arguments);
            },

            parse: function (resp) {
                if (resp.success) {
                    return resp.success;
                }
                else if (resp.error) {
                    return this.models;
                }
                else {
                    return resp;
                }
            },

  });

  var UsersCollection = BaseCollection.extend({

            constructor: function () {   //this will override the constructor in BaseCollection, but I want both...
               this.givenName = '@UsersCollection';
               Backbone.Collection.apply(this, arguments);
            },

            initialize: function (models, opts) {
            //do something here 
            }

        });
```

Is there a better way to do it? One problem that I have is that I can't override constructor twice, I can only override it in the parent (BaseCollection) class. So is there a way to chain constructors? Or do I pretty much only have two options?

Comment: You're still implementing `constructor` instead of `initialize`, why is that? You're also still doing `this.givenName = '@UsersCollection'` when `givenName: '@UsersCollection'` would make more sense. There are [lots of ways to implementing `super` in Backbone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8596861/479863) so chaining shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Mu, I was partly wrong. givenName: '@UsersCollection' definitely hides that property in the proto. However, setting this.givenName in the initialize function puts it in the top level of the Backbone object. So I will get rid of the constructor property in the subclass, but using the constructor property in the superclass seems to give me what I want.

Comment: without needing/wanting to use this.givenName in the constructor of the subclass, I have no current need to use the constructor property, so I will get rid of it at your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just `extend` and `apply` from the `BaseCollection` instead of the `Backbone.Collection` to get the results you want from your example:

```
var BaseCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    constructor: function () {
        // your base collection constructor

        // run the Backbone.Collection constructor on this
        Backbone.Collection.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});

// extends methods on BaseCollection
var UserCollection = BaseCollection.extend({
    constructor: function () {
        // your user collection constructor

        // run the BaseCollection constructor on this
        BaseCollection.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```