# jQuery widget and internal callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

This doesn't work, but gives you the idea: a widget needs to use its own method as a callbacK:

```
$.widget("me.mywidget", {

    _create: function() {
        this.call("mymodule", "myaction", {arg: this.options.value}, _parseData);
    },

    _parseData: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },

    call: function(module, action, params, callback) {
        var params = params || {};
        var url = "/" + module + "/"  + action;

        $.post(url, params, function(data) {
            if (data.payload) callback(data.payload);
        });
    },
});
```

It currently throws the exception: `Uncaught ReferenceError: _parseData is not defined`

What's the canonical way of doing this?

Comment: Jeez, that was too easy. I didn't even think about it.

Comment: Well, using that and 'this' in the callback is window, rather than the widget object, which is undesirable

Answer (score 0):

The $.post callback needs to call your own `callback` using `.apply` or `.call`, both of which allow you to set what the scope of `this` is in the function you call.

```
call: function(module, action, params, callback) {
    var params = params || {};
    var url = "/" + module + "/"  + action;
    var self = this;

    $.post(url, params, function(data) {
        if (data.payload) callback.apply(self, [ data.payload ]);
    });
},
```

Or:

```
call: function(module, action, params, callback) {
    var params = params || {};
    var url = "/" + module + "/"  + action;

    $.post(url, params, function(data) {
        if (data.payload) callbac.call(self, data.payload);
    });
},
```

You can [read this for more information on apply/call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply).