# callback function with a parameter

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I know how to write a callback function with coffee-script,like this:

*test1.coffee*

```
exports.cube=(callback)-> 
    callback(5)
```

*test2.coffee*

```
test1=require('./test1')

test1.cube (result) ->
    console.log(result)
```

I want to know how to add a parameter into callback function?
so that I can use it like this:

```
test1.cube(para,result)->
    //use *para* to compute a *result*
    //here can do something with *result*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you want is this:

```
cube = (x, callback) ->
  callback(x * x * x)

cube 3, (result) ->
  console.log 'the cube of 3 is ', result
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in methods apply() or call() like

```
callback.call(...)
callback.apply(...)
```

Here is more about how and the difference between them:
[What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)