# endless prototype javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I am attempting to create an endless prototype function. Here is my attempt, which is not working:

```
function Cat(name, direction) {
this.name = name;
this.stand = {left: "images/standLeft.png", right: "images/standRight.png"};
this.walk = {left: "images/walkLeft.gif", right: "images/walkRight.gif"};
this.direction = direction;
}

Cat.prototype.walking = function() {
var myDirection = (this.direction == "right" ? "+=": "-=");
var myPosition = $("#cat").css("left");
myPosition = myPosition.substring(0, myPosition.length - 2);

var distanceLeft = myPosition;
var distanceRight = 1024 - myPosition - 173;


if(this.direction == "right") {
    var distance = distanceRight;
} else {
    var distance = distanceLeft;
}
    $("#cat img")[0].src =  this.walk[this.direction];
    $("#cat").animate({
        left: myDirection + distance
        }, (22.85 * distance), function(){
            this.direction = (this.direction == "right" ? "left": "right");
             this.walking();
        });
}

var myCat = new Cat("Izzy", "right");
```

I thought calling `(this.walking())` would run the same function again with the same object, however it is throwing an error. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` there will be window scope.

```
$("#cat img")[0].src =  this.walk[this.direction];
var that = this;
$("#cat").animate({
    left: myDirection + distance
    }, (22.85 * distance), function(){
        that.direction = (that.direction == "right" ? "left": "right");
         that.walking();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See my explanation of scope handling in JavaScript (and jQuery) on [this StackOvervlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187668/why-is-it-necessary-to-wrap-function-call-in-a-function-body/14188501#14188501). In your case, you should just accept that jQuery will choose `this` to be something other than your cat object. Also note that jQuery works with a HTML element, not with an instance of cat, so even if it wanted to it couldn't set `this` = your cat object.

You can alleviate the problem by wrapping the function in [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) ([link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)), like so:

```
// This is your original handler. I made this a named function for clarity.
var animateHandler = function() {
    this.direction = (this.direction == "right" ? "left": "right");
    this.walking();
}

// Now here's your original call to animate.
$("#cat").animate(
    { left: myDirection + distance},
    (22.85 * distance),
    animateHandler
);

// Here's what you'd change it to.
$("#cat").animate(
    { left: myDirection + distance },
    (22.85 * distance),
    $.proxy(animateHandler, this)
);
```