# "this" context for .on() function jQuery

Tags: jquery, this

I would like to know how to point `this` to the selected element (event source) inside `.on()` method without defining an anonymous event handling function.

For example, in the code bellow, the context for my selected element is `document`, i.e. `$(this)` is interpreted as `document`

```js
$('.nav-item').click(MyFrameworkUtils.navigationBinding($(this), 'arg1', 'arg2'))
```

However, if wrapped in an anonymous event handler, `$(this)` is interpreted (desirably) as the selected element.

```js
$('.nav-item').click(function(){
    var source = $(this);
    MyFrameworkUtils.navigationBinding(source, 'arg1', 'arg2');
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this syntax:

```
$('.nav-item').click({arg1:'arg1', arg2:'arg2'}, MyFrameworkUtils.navigationBinding)
```

and the function would look like this:

```
function navigationBinding(event) {
    var source = $(this);
    var arg1 = event.data.arg1;
    var arg2 = event.data.arg2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, you're passing the result of `MyFrameworkUtils.navigationBinding($(this), 'arg1', 'arg2')` into your `click` method. The context of `this` is therefore the context is the outer scope, which is the `document` in your case.

With the second example however the scope is the inner function, and as with most events triggered by the DOM, `this` is the triggering element.

Additionally [possibly unrelated], when calling functions you can define `this` by using the `apply` or `call` methods, as described quite nicely in [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Comment: Thanksssss. It makes a lot of sense.. well, Javascript sense. And thanks for suggesting the apply and call functions.