# Idiomatic usage of apply in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm sorry if this is a truly basic question, but some code I've seen got me curious.

What is the idiomatic usage of the `apply` function?

For instance, I've seen code written in the form:

```
(distinct [1 2 3 4 5 6])
```

and

```
(apply distinct? [1 2 3 4 5 6])
```

These return the same result, and even in the docs, it clearly says:

> ;; Note the equivalence of the following two forms
>
> user=> (apply str ["str1" "str2" "str3"]) "str1str2str3"
>
> user=> (str "str1" "str2" "str3") "str1str2str3"

Is this example simply too basic to convey the usefulness of `apply`? Or am I missing a fundamental difference between the two?

When is one form regarded as best over the other?

Comment: Presumably `apply` has utility beyond this example.  Can the other five examples in the [Clojure documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply) be converted into forms that do not use `apply` without making them more complex or less performant, or eliminating features?

Comment: Thinking a bit more about the examples, I see the usefulness when treating a collection as individual arguments passed to the function. I think I was too hasty in my evaluation.

Comment: Some cases where `apply` is needed or wanted (1) unknown variadic arguments `(apply + (range (rand-int 42)))`, (2) mapping a function to a collection of collections `(map (partial apply +) [[1 2][3 4]])`, (3) avoiding explicit destructing when arguments arrive in a collection `(= (let [pair [7 3]] (apply mod pair)) (let [[a b] [7 5]] (mod a b))`, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
user=> (apply str ["str1" "str2" "str3"]) "str1str2str3"

user=> (str "str1" "str2" "str3") "str1str2str3"
```

In this example, the advantage of using `apply` is that it can take a list of strings. `str`, by itself, cannot.

I'm no expert, but my instinct says that you shouldn't use `apply` unless necessary. Therefore, if you have a collection of values that you want to pass to a variadic function, `apply` is useful — otherwise, just use the plain function, e.g. `str`.

Answer (score 4):

These are both true, but for very different reasons:

```
(distinct? [1 2 3 4 5 6])
;=> true
```

There is only one argument, the vector of 1..6,
and it is distinct from any other argument because there
*are* no other arguments

```
(apply distinct? [1 2 3 4 5 6])
;=> true
```

There are 6 arguments, all of which are distinct.

Observe:

```
(distinct? [1 1 1])
;=> true
```

There is only one argument, the vector of three `1`s

```
(apply distinct? [1 1 1])
;=> false
```

There are three arguments, all three of which are `1`.

Note the difference:

```
(str [1 2 3])
;=> "[1 2 3]" -- single argument of a vector stringified

(apply str [1 2 3])
;=> "123" -- three arguments each stringified and concatenated
```

Apply effects the transformation `(apply f [a b c]) => (f a b c)`, which is generally *not* the same as `(f [a b c])`.

Comment: He used `distinct`, not `distinct?` in his first case. Not sure whether that was a typo or not.

Comment: You're right, being a complete newbie to Clojure, I did an additional mistake, messing up `distinct` and `distinct?`, two different functions... thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` when you want to treat a collection as the arguments of a function. In the case of `distinct` it takes a collection as it's argument, so it's not necessary to use `apply`.

```
(distinct [1 2 3 4 1 1])
;returns: (1 2 3 4)
```

`distinct?` returns true if it's arguments are distinct:

```
(distinct? [1 2 3 4 1 1])
;returns true because there's only one argument
```

`apply` uses the items in the collection as arguments:

```
(apply distinct? [1 2 3 4 1 1])
;returns false because of the duplicated 1's
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I use `apply` to transform a vector to arguments when calling a function. This is a lot like the `apply` function found in JavaScript as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Functions such as `str` are variadic and expect the same type as input, in this case, anything that implements `toString`. Using `(str a b c)` is idiomatic, `(apply str [a b c])` is not.

The function `apply` can be used when you have a heterogeneous vector whose items you would like to use as arguments to a function. You may find the need to create a list of vectors where the items in the vector correspond to the arguments of your function, then it's necessary to use `apply`.

I think of `apply` as: exploding the vector into arguments.

Example:

```
(def authtypes [:basic :basic :oauth])
(def usernames ["charlie" "snoopy" "lisa"])
(def passwords ["brown" "dog" "maggie"])

(let [credentials (map vector authtypes usernames passwords)]
  (doseq [c credentials]
    (apply login-user c)))
```