# .call() / .apply() with NO parameters VS simply calling a function with () parenthesis

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I've seen it done differently in code out there, but is there any benefit or reason to doing a (blank params) **.call / .apply** over a regular **()** function execution.

This of course is an over-simplified example

```
var func = function () { /* do whatever */ };

func.call();
func.apply();
```

*VERSUS* just the simple parenthesis.

```
func();
```

Haven't seen any information on this anywhere, I know why call/apply are used when params are passed.

Comment: @FeistyMango: Definitely not a dupe of that.

Comment: Where have you seen such code?  I thought (and answered) that it was to make sure `this` is empty, but that's not the case.  As far as I can tell through some quick experiments, it's a pointless practice.

Comment: Sure it is. He is asking the benefit/reasons for call vs apply. Isn't that essentially the same as asking the difference between the two???

Comment: Nope, he's asking the reasons to use `.call` or `.apply` without a `this` argument versus simply calling the function.

Comment: @FeistyMango I was putting the 2 in the same category, I was looking more at why would someone do a blank param `funcName.call();` versus `funcName();`

Comment: @FeistyMango read the question - he's asking about using **either** `.call()` **or** `.apply()` with no arguments instead of just calling a function directly

Comment: @Pointy I've just seen it randomly here and there, always blew my mind, it must of been someone that didn't understand how to use `.call/apply` correctly. I guess if it keeps the global window object as the normal `()` call does, it's identical then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call a method with `func();`, `this` variable inside the method points to `window` object.

Where as when you use [call(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[apply(...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) the first parameter passed to the method call becomes `this` inside the method. If you are not passing any arguments/pass null or undefined then `this` will [become global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters) in non strict mode.

Comment: Nope, `this` will still point to the global object, unless you explicitly pass `undefined` as the first argument.

Comment: Bart is correct - in fact `this` will be `window` even when you explicitly pass `null` or `undefined`.  In "strict" mode it works, but then just plain `func()` also gets `this` set to `undefined`.

Comment: @Bart yes you are right https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: Wow very interesting, definitely good to know! So maybe some of the code I had seen (wish I could find an example right now) was in Strict mode intending it to be undefined, not sure why they'd want that..

Comment: Then again, if you're in strict mode, `this` will not reference the global object either if a simple func() call is made. So even in strict mode, I don't see any reason to use `func.call()` without a `this` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an important difference in some cases. For example, dealing with callbacks. Let's assume you have a class with constructor that accepts `callback` parameter and stores it under `this.callback`. Later, when this callback is invoked via `this.callback()`, suddenly the foreign code gets the reference to your object via `this`. It is not always desirable, and it is better/safer to use `this.callback.call()` in such case.

That way, the foreign code will get `undefined` as `this` and won't try to modify your object by accident. And properly written callback won't be affected by this usage of `call()` anyways, since they would supply the callback defined as an arrow function or as bound function (via `.bind()`). In both such cases, the callback will have its own, proper this, unaffected by `call()`, since arrow and bound functions just ignore the value, set by `apply()/call()`.