# Security: Passing a function as a parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-security

I am very very new to JavaScript, so please bear with me!.

I was wondering if you pass a function as a parameter to another function in JavaScript, for example (disclaimer: the code may not be 100% correct, but you should get the idea!):

```
function(param1, param2) {

   ....
   // Do something with param 1
   param1 += 10;
   ....

   // Param 2 is a function, so call it
   param2();

   .....
}
```

Is this a potential **security risk**, or is this a common way of programming in JavaScript?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, functions are **first class** citizens. You can assign a function to a **var**, pass functions as `arguments` to other functions or `return` a function as a result from another function.

There are many methods in JavaScript that accept a function as an argument(also called callback functions).
One such example is forEach

```
Array.prototype.forEach();

var elements = [42, 33, 45, 5];

elements.forEach(/*anonymous function*/function(element, index) {
// do something with element
});

elements.forEach(callback);

function callback(element, index) {
//do something with element
}
```

Comment: So there is no security issue in doing this?

Comment: @Mewzer just remember to leave off the parenthesis `()` when you pass a function as a parameter as you are just passing the function reference into the new function and not calling it

Answer (score 1):

I can say it's very common in js, you can see usage as in apply and call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

[What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

but it may impose security risks if the function (param2) is passed two you from user or third-party that you do not trust (eg. you offer some server like widget to third-parties)