# Where do function arguments exist when using .call()/.apply()?

Tags: javascript

i came across a situation where I need to call another function with .call() or .apply() like this:

```
function b() {
  alert(arg);
}
```

Then

```
function a(arg) {
  b.call();
}
a(123);
```

Function b is called, but doesnt' have access to ***arg.*** That's ok, I can pass scope.. yes?

```
function a(arg) {
  b.call(this);
}
a(123);
```

Still no - I can't access ***arg*** from function b. How can I do it?

**UPDATE**:
I do not want to modify b function :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between call and apply?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Comment: Before going anywhere, your first line should read: function b(arg) {

Comment: @meagar I am not asking for difference..

Comment: @joeytwiddle as per update, I do not want to modify b function. I want the solution to be elegant and with minimal effort :)

Comment: Then you should have accepted Engineer's answer!  There is not much use using call or apply to pass the correct argument to `b` if your `b` function does not accept any arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to pass the arguments via `call` (individually) or `apply` (as an array):

```
function a(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  b.call(this, arg1, arg2, arg3);
  // or 
  b.apply(this, arguments)
  // or
  b.apply(this, [arg1, arg2, arg3]);
}
```

Of course, nothing about your situation suggests actually *using* `call` or `apply`: Just invoke the function yourself.

```
function a(arg) {
  b(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It’s not possible to “pass scope” or something like that. The scope of a function is determined when the function is created, so it can only access `arg` if it exists where `b` is defined.

If `arg` was part of `this`, then you could do this using `call`, i.e. make the `this` in `b` the same `this` as it is in `a` (of course this will modify whatever `this` actually refers to, which can have side effects you might not want to happen).

```
function a (arg) {
    this.arg = arg;
    b.call(this);
}

function b () {
    console.log(this.arg);
}
```

The other way would be to just pass the argument to `b` as an actual function argument. You can access all arguments of a function using `arguments`:

```
function b () {
    console.log(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
function a(arg) {
    b.apply(this, [arg]);
    // or
    // b.call(this, arg);
}

function b() {
    alert(arguments);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess the problem lies in b(). There's no 'arg' argument defined. Try:
`function b(arg) { alert(arg);  }`
and

```
function a(arg) {
  b.call(this,arg);
}
a(123);
```

now it runs

(Update: the call needs the arguments ( context functionarg1, functionarg2...) )

Comment: after adding the context "this" to call() it runs ;-)

Comment: Sorry, as per update I really do not want to modify functio b :)

Answer (score 0):

You failed to pass the arguments when you called `b`.

`Function::call` allows you to pass a fixed number of arguments:

```
function a(arg1,arg2) {
    return b.call(this,arg1,arg2);
}
```

`Function::apply` allows you to pass any number of arguments, as an array:

```
function a(arg1,arg2) {
    return b.apply(this,[arg1,arg2]);
}

// or

function a(arg1,arg2) {
    return b.apply(this,arguments);   // The magical 'arguments' variable
}
```

`this` is the context object, and is not the same thing as scope.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that, for some reasons you can't modify the body of `b` , you can try something like this:

```
function a(arg) {
   eval("("+ b.toString() +")()");
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zRNCr/)

Comment: I hope, someone will explain why I should assume that *arg* and *arguments* are the same thing for the OP.

Comment: They are not the same, and OP does not imply that either (I doubt OP was even aware of `arguments`). While your code does what OP wants (evaluate `b` within a scope where `arg` is available), using `eval` should not be an option.

Comment: @poke Only the OP knows what should be an option and what should not.

Comment: @poke what if the OP can't modify the body of `b`?

Comment: Funny.  Makes it work without having to fix the `b` function!