# using event listeners and parsing this from unnamed function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple event listener but need to parse `this` through it to my function but don't know how.

This is what i have so far:

```
var inpt = document.getElementById('curq');
inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function(e,max){ int_inpt_only(e,max); } , false);

function int_inpt_only(e,max) {
                this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
                if(this.value > max) this.value = max;
                if(this.value<1)this.value=1;
}
```

The problem is `this` is not defined in my function because the scope does not carry through, so i am wondering how i link them without having to look up the element two times.

Comment: you can use that=e.target; and then that instead of this instead of call/bind/apply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    int_inpt_only.call(this, e, 100);
}, false);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4WMss/5/)

---

There was also a small quirk with your posted handler logic:

```
inpt.addEventListener("keyup", function(e,max){ int_inpt_only(e,max); } , false);
                                          ^^^
```

Event handlers don't receive a second argument so `max` is undefined there.

---

Or, if that is all your event handler does and the `int_inpt_only` can access the `max` variable through lexical scope (e.g. defined in an outer scope), just pass a function reference as event handler instead:

```
inpt.addEventListener("keyup", int_inpt_only, false);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4WMss/6/)

Comment: Hmm you suggest `.call` and cory suggests `.apply` is there any differences ?

Comment: Not many. They have the same effect, just that `apply`'s 2nd parameter takes an array of arguments while `.call()` uses passes the 2nd to nth parameters as arguments.

Comment: Is there a way to stop it displaying the letter in the input box before removing it again ?

Comment: In modern browsers you can use `"input"` instead of `"keyup"`. That should solve the delay I believe. `=]`

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the event handler like this:

```
inpt.addEventListener("keyup", 
    function(e, max) { int_inpt_only.apply(this, [e, max]); } , false);
```

Comment: Hmm you suggest `.apply` and Frabricio suggests `.call` is there any differences ?

Comment: Some slight differences in syntax but basically the same functionality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply

Comment: `apply` tends to be slower than `call`, so use `call` if possible (which is in this case)

Comment: @Koen: You are very correct. I didn't know this, but the difference is rather suprising (at least in Chrome): http://jsperf.com/function-versus-function-call-versus-function-apply