# How do I take in a event variable in Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This feels like a amateurish question, but how do you **take in an event** in a custom function in Javascript / jQuery?

Right now I'm using this:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(event){
    removeButton();
});

function removeButton() {
    $(this).removeClass("specifiedClass");
}
```

I'm trying to make `removeButton()` understand that I want it to remove the class that is on the `.button` itself.

I'm not sure how to make `removeButton()` take in the event, but I've tried:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(event){
    removeButton(event);
});

function removeButton(event) {
    $(this).removeClass("specifiedClass");
}
```

But its not working. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need pass the element as a parameter:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(event){
    removeButton(this);
});

function removeButton(elem) {
    $(elem).removeClass("specifiedClass");
}
```

Comment: oh wow. its working perfectly. awesome! also, is it recommended to put it as `removeButton(event)`? Or should I put it as some other variable so as to avoid conflict?

Comment: You are working with an element .. I would make it elem like in the example.

Answer (score 1):

SLaks' solution is perfectly acceptable, but if you didn't want to change your `removeButton` function, you could use [`call` or `apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply) to invoke your function with the proper `this` value:

```
$(".button").on("click", function(event){
    removeButton.call(this);
});

function removeButton() {
    $(this).removeClass("specifiedClass");
}
```