# How can I extend an object with Javascript's prototype using variables in the declaration?

Tags: javascript

I've tried searching for but perhaps I am describing it incorrectly since I'm not having any luck finding results.

I want to do this:

```
    XS.prototype.Abc=function $Def(a,c){ ... }
```

But I would like `XS`, `ABC`, and `$Def` to be variables ( dynamic)

For `XS` since this is in the global scope I think that I can use `window[]` like this:

```
var myindex = 'XS';
window[myindex].prototype.Abc=function $Def(a,c){ ... }
```

I read over [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply) but I still can't figure out if it would be possible to use `call` or `apply` to do the other two as variables.

Comment: Well, `Abc` is easy: `.prototype[Abc]`. Please see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators) for more information. Regarding `$Def`, it's not possible (and the name of a function expression is only accessibly from within a function, so you might not even have to name the function). `.call` and `.apply` have nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[]` notation on any object:

```
window[ctorName].prototype[methodName] = function() { };
```

However, AFAIK, there is no non-evil way to set a function's name dynamically.