# Why is call so much faster than apply?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if anyone knows *why* `call` is so much faster than `apply`?  In chrome, it's roughly 4x faster, and 30x in firefox, and I can even make a custom prototype, `apply2`, that does (in most cases) run 2x as fast as `apply` (the idea taken from angular):

```
Function.prototype.apply2 = function( self, arguments ){
    switch( arguments.length ){
         case 1:  this.call( self, arguments[0] );                                                                                                                               break;
         case 2:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1] );                                                                                                                 break;
         case 3:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2] );                                                                                                   break;
         case 4:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3] );                                                                                     break;
         case 5:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4] );                                                                       break;
         case 6:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], arguments[5] );                                                         break;
         case 7:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], arguments[5], arguments[6] );                                           break;
         case 8:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], arguments[5], arguments[6], arguments[7] );                             break;
         case 9:  this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], arguments[5], arguments[6], arguments[7], arguments[8] );               break;
         case 10: this.call( self, arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4], arguments[5], arguments[6], arguments[7], arguments[8], arguments[9] ); break;
         default: this.apply( self, arguments ); break;
    }   
};
```

So does anyone know why?

Comment: I thought this site provides some interesting statistics http://jsperf.com/function-calls-direct-vs-apply-vs-call-vs-bind/6

Comment: This jsperf also shows call outperforming http://jsperf.com/apply-vs-call

Comment: This answer and comment(s) has some discussion about possible reasons why call may be faster than apply: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8040293/1253479

Answer (score 16):

Referencing the [ECMAScript Language Specification 5.1 Edition (June 2011)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/):

### 15.3.4.3 Function.prototype.apply (thisArg, argArray)

When the `apply` method is called on an object func with arguments thisArg and argArray, the following steps are taken:

1. If `IsCallable(func)` is `false`, then throw a `TypeError` exception.
2. If `argArray` is `null` or `undefined`, then
               `return` the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal method of `func`, providing `thisArg` as the `this` value and an empty list of arguments.
3. If `Type(argArray)` is not `Object`, then throw a `TypeError` exception.
4. Let `len` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of
   `argArray` with argument `"length"`.
5. Let `n` be `ToUint32(len)`.
6. Let `argList` be an empty `List`.
7. Let `index` be 0.
8. Repeat while `index < n`
9. Let `indexName` be `ToString(index)`.
10. Let `nextArg` be the result of calling the `[[Get]]` internal method of
     `argArray` with `indexName` as the argument.
11. Append `nextArg` as the last element of `argList`.
12. Set `index` to `index + 1`.
13. Return the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal method of `func`,
     providing `thisArg` as the `this` value and `argList` as the list of
         arguments.

### 15.3.4.4 Function.prototype.call (thisArg [ , arg1 [ , arg2, … ] ] )

When the `call` method is called on an object func with argument thisArg and optional arguments arg1, arg2 etc, the following steps are taken:

1. If `IsCallable(func)` is `false`, then throw a `TypeError` exception.
2. Let `argList` be an empty `List`.
3. If this method was called with more than one argument then in left
   to right order starting with `arg1` append each argument as the last
   element of `argList`
4. Return the result of calling the `[[Call]]` internal method of `func`,
   providing `thisArg` as the `this` value and `argList` as the list of
   arguments.

---

As we can see, the format in which `apply` is specified is notably heavier and needs to do a lot more due to the need to change the format in which the arguments are given and how they are finally needed.
There are a number of checks in `apply` which are not necessary in `call` due to the difference of input formatting.

Another key point is the manner in which arguments are looped over (steps 4-12 in `apply`, implied in step 3 of `call`): the whole set-up for looping is executed in `apply` regardless of how many arguments there actually are, in `call` all of this is done only if needed.
Additionally it's worthwhile noting that the way in which step 3 in `call` is implemented isn't specified, which would help explain the drastic differences in different browser behavior.

So to shortly recap: `call` is faster than `apply` because the input parameters are already formatted as necessary for the internal method.

Be sure to read the comments below for further discussion.

Comment: There's an implied loop in step 3 for `.call()` as well -- "*in left to right order starting with arg1 append each argument as the last element of argList*"

Comment: There's a loop in `call` as well (how else is step #3 going to be implemented?), so I 'm not at all sure this is relevant.

Comment: @Jon The loop in `call` is conditional and is executed only if necessary, the loop in `apply` is always executed.

Comment: @Nit A `while` with an immediately failing condition shouldn't burn that much more processing than an `if`-wrapped loop with a failing condition.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski The set-up steps 6;7 of the loop in `apply` will be executed regardless of whether they're necessary or not (ignoring steps 4;5, as `call` will also need to check for length).

Comment: Additionally I think it's worthwhile noting that the way in which step 3 in `call` is implemented isn't specified, which would help explain the drastic differences in different browser behavior.