# Array of functions - execute single function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have something like this:

```
var functions = ['function1','function2','function3'];
```

How would I run a certain function?

```
function[0];
```

Ideally I would like to use a count of some sort to call a function individually. I am able to get the correct output but it does not actually execute the function.

Thanks!

Comment: You are storing strings (function names) in your array, not functions. Are these functions defined in the global scope? Are they methods exposed by a specific object?

Comment: Well, I changed the from function names to functions using this as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/mzxCk/. It however only appears to work in firefox and not chrome (the browser I am testing in).

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me on Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m.

Comment: And for me. It works in firfox, i at least have something to work with. Thanks for all the help . Your time is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var array_of_functions = [
    first,
    second,
    third,
    forth
]
```

and call like

```
array_of_functions[count](parameters);
```

example

```
array_of_functions[0]();
```

or

```
array_of_functions[0]('string');
```

**JSFIDDLE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/mzxCk/

Comment: You should note that `first`, `second` etc, obviously need to be defined as functions first (e.g. `function first() { //do something }`

Comment: They are defined, but still does not execute. Does the placement of the function matter?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
window[functions[0]]();
               //^---------- use index here
```

Use bracket notation to get the function name and call it by `()`.

This answer assumes that you have those functions with those names in global scope.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ86y/)

Comment: Thats what I thought but it does not seem to work. If I output that in an alert, it shows the function name as expected, but it does not execute as expected.

Comment: @user3291686, check out my demo

Answer (score 0):

You also need to consider calling scope, which is why you should be using `call` or `apply` depending on whether you're passing your arguments as separate objects or an array [see here for a description of both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply).

If your `functions` contains a collection of strings, you'll need to invoke them (with args) like this (note the `this` as the first param of call, this is the scope the function will run under, so in this case `window`):

```
var func1 = function (msg) {
  document.write("func1 called with message - " + msg + ".");
};
var functions = ['func1', 'func2'];
window[functions[0]].call(this, 'here is a message');
```

If `functions` contains a collection of `Function` then you need to call them like this:

```
var functions = [
  function (msg) {
    document.write("func1 called with message - " + msg + ".");
  },
  function (msg) {
    document.write("func2 called with message - " + msg + ".");
  }];
functions[0].call(this, 'here is a message');
```