# Call dynamic function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

my code:

```
var MyObj = {
    myFnc = function(a, b) {
       console.log('A: '+a+', B: '+b);
    }
}

var list = new Array('myFnc', new Array('var1', 'var2'));
MyObj[list[0]].call(list[1]);
```

but not working, somebody can help me?

Comment: What are you expecting the code to do?

Comment: Do you see an error in the console?

Comment: ALWAYS check the error console. You have a syntax error in constructing your object. You need a `:`, not an `=` when assigning the function.

Comment: what isn't working about it? is it throwing an error? what is the error?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you want to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/1048572). And don't forget about the first parameter, which is the `this` context!

```
var MyObj = {
    myFnc: function(a, b) {
       console.log('A: '+a+', B: '+b);
    };
}

var list = ['myFnc', ['var1', 'var2']];
MyObj[list[0]].apply(MyObj, list[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.apply` instead of `.call` and supply a context to the apply function:

```
var MyObj = {
    myFnc : function(a, b) {
       console.log('A: '+a+', B: '+b);
    }
};

var list = new Array('myFnc', new Array('var1', 'var2'));
MyObj[list[0]].apply(window, list[1]);
```

`.apply` calls the function and uses the specified array as the parameters.

Additionally, use a colon instead of an equals sign when defining `myFnc`.