# JavaScript Call or Apply using Knockout ViewModelBase

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this base view model:

```
var baseViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    // <!----- AJAX SAVING ------!> \\
    self.saving = ko.observable();

    // <!----- SEARCHING ------!> \\
    self.fields = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedField = ko.observable();
    self.searchTerm = ko.observable().extend({ throttle: 150 });
}
```

And I inherit it using this:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    baseViewModel.call(this);
    var self = this;

    //stufff
}
viewModel.prototype = new baseViewModel();
```

And it works perfectly. Quite pleased with it.

Now, I want to setup the `self.fields` property with some initial data, that I want to send through the line `baseViewModel.call(this)` and I'm not sure whether to do this:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    baseViewModel.call(this, new userModel()); // just a function object
    var self = this;
}
```

OR:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    baseViewModel.apply(this, new userModel()); // just a function object
    var self = this;
}
```

So that the `baseViewModel` will do this:

```
var baseViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    // <!----- AJAX SAVING ------!> \\
    self.saving = ko.observable();

    // <!----- SEARCHING ------!> \\
    self.fields = ko.observableArray().getKeys(data); // viewModel parameter passed here
    self.selectedField = ko.observable();
    self.searchTerm = ko.observable().extend({ throttle: 150 });
}
```

I have read this [Difference between call and apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply) still not sure where to go and I have read the official documentation.

***EDIT***

I have just tried `call` because as I understand it the only difference is either putting in a bunch or args (with `call`) or putting in an array of args (with `apply`)

Its worked with `call` so far, just wondering if there are going to be any caveats with choosing this method?

Comment: you use apply when the arguments you want to pass are in an array, since your userModel object is not in an array just use call

Comment: fair enough, no caveats then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there are any caveats, the only difference is whether the `args` come as and array or separate objects

[Call Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

[Apply Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

with `call` you do `baseViewModel.call(this [, arg1, arg2, .... argn])`

with `apply` you do `baseViewModel.apply(this [, arg_array[] ])`