# How to determine which way chained functions execute when "call" is used?

Tags: javascript

So for example, in `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`, `call` comes before `slice` but in var `standard= name.substring(1).toLowerCase()` `substring` is called before `toLowerCase`. Why is there this difference and how do I know which order functions are called in when you chain them?

Comment: `call` calls the function `slice`. There's only one function call there.

Comment: Learn about [call and apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Comment: but isn't call a prototype of function? And slice is a prototype of array, and substring is a prototype and toLowerCase is a prototype

Comment: the function 'slice' is being borrowed from prototype and being called on the object in arguments. There's no chaining of functions like in your substring example.

Comment: Sort of. Again, go learn what `call` does and the answer will be clear.

Comment: Function execution in javascript is done with parenthesis. You are comparing apples with oranges. The first line executes one function (call), the second executes two (substring and then toLowerCase)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstands something... it is simply

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`

only invokes one function which is `slice()`

`.call()` invokes `slice()` function and `.call()` is a method of `slice`

so

`call()` **calls the previous method** with the provided context and arguments. which makes its right to left until only the previous function before `call()`

and with regards to chaining

***Chaining** simply means that you use the return value of a function you  invoke and that value is an object that contains a method you invoke again.* so it happens from left to right

the best example is

```
var firststr = "my house".substring(2); //then this returns a string
var secondstr = firststr.trim(); //method call trim() on the return of .substring()
```

that can be rewritten as

```
"my house".substring(2).trim();
```

**MUST READ:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: but why isn't it something like Array.prototype.call(arguments).slice?

Comment: @slynthin because that doesn't make any sense. Seriously, go [read about call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to understand why what you're asking is nonsense. `call` says "call the previous method with the provided context and arguments." It's not chaining.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `prototype` and `slice` are properties of the `Array` object:

```
Array.prototype.slice  // On the Array.prototype object, get `.slice` property
```

Then, with the `.slice` property, get the property `.call` on it and execute that.  In this example, only `.call()` is a method invocation (e.g. a function call).  This is not chaining at all.  This is just nested property declarations, not chaining.

Chaining like your other example:

```
var standard = name.substring(1).toLowerCase()
```

executes left to right.  `name.substring(1)` is executed and on the return result from that method, the `.toLowerCase()` method is called.  Chaining only works if the prior methods return appropriate object types for the follow-on methods.  In this case, a new string object is returned by `name.substring(1)` and `.toLowerCase()` is called on that new string object.  Thus things execute from left to right.

Comment: okay, I guess I'm just confused because MDN defined call/slice/substring/toLowerCase as all prototypes, so in my mind I think of them as under the same category so I expect all of them to read in one direction

Comment: @slynthin - It is slightly confusing.  They are methods on a prototype and can be referenced on objects of that type.  One uses `Array.prototype.slice` only when you don't already have the appropriate array to call `.slice()` on.  If you had an array already, you would just call `array.slice()` and not need to specify the prototype.  Then, `.slice` is an instantiated function object which has `.call()` on it's prototype so you can do `slice.call()`.

Comment: `call` is a method on the `Function` prototype. `slice` is on `String/Array` and `substring/toLowerCase` are on `String`. You are conflating prototypal inheritance, method invocation, nested lookups, and chaining into one mess of confusion.

Comment: @slynthin - said a different way.  When a function is defined on a prototype, that means you can get access to that function two ways.  First, you can specify it on the prototype as in `Array.prototype.slice`.  Second, it will automatically be available on any object of that type as in `var array = [1,2,3];  var x = array.slice(1);`.  If a function is defined on an object's prototype, then MDN tells you which prototype it is defined on and thus which object type it is associated with.  Other functions like `eval()` are not defined on a specific prototype as they are just globally available.

Answer (score 0):

`slice` is a property (which happens to be a function) of `Array.prototype`, and you're using `call` to invoke that function (that's **one** function call). `name.substring(1).toLowerCase()` chains the functions `substring` and `toLowerCase` (in that order).