# Javascript "class" extension with parameters?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I would like to "extend" a new class from an existing class and include it's methods and parameter construction.

```
System = function(name, hp){
  this.name = name;
  this.hp = [];
  this.setHP = function(hp){
     this.hp[0] = hp;
     this.hp[1] = hp;
  }
  this.setHP(hp);
}

Weapon = function(name, hp){
   System.call(this);
}

Weapon.prototype = new System(name, hp);
Weapon.prototype.constructor = Weapon;


var gun = new Weapon("Gun", 10);    // undefined name, hp
var hangar = new System("Hangar", 10);    // works
```

So, this is as far as i got, and someone is obviously wrong.
Can someone advise me ?

Comment: `call` requires parameters 
`Weapon = function(name, hp){ System.call(this, name, hp);
}`

Comment: May i inquire about which solution better to use ? Expand the call or use apply as suggested ?

Comment: @Cristian F [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments in the call:

```
System.call(this, name, hp);
```

Also, be aware that `Weapon.prototype = new System(name, hp);` can have side-effects, it is better practice to use:

```
Weapon.prototype = Object.create(System.prototype);
```

You can find polyfills for `Object.create` if you need to support ancient browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
System = function(name, hp){
  this.name = name;
  this.hp = [];
  this.setHP = function(hp){
     this.hp[0] = hp;
     this.hp[1] = hp;
  }
  this.setHP(hp);
}
Weapon = function(name, hp){
    System.apply(this, arguments);
}

console.log(new Weapon("Gun", 10));
console.log(new System("Hangar", 10));
```

Result:

```
Weapon {name: "Gun", hp: Array[2], setHP: function}
System {name: "Hangar", hp: Array[2], setHP: function}
```