# Yet another Call vs Apply query

Tags: javascript

When I tried to run the following piece of code:

```
function flatten(a) {
  return [].slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(acc, val) {
    return acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? flatten.call(null, val) : val);
  }, []);
}
```

I got the following error:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

But if I used `flatten.apply` instead of `flatten.call`, it works perfectly. (deep flattens the input array).

In addition to this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply) and [link2](http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-apply-call-and-bind-methods-are-essential-for-javascript-professionals/), I read few other blogs and articles to understand why it behaves so. I either couldn't find the answer or I must have overlooked it. (pardon my soar eyes if in latter case)

Of course, the fundamental difference between these 2 is:

> apply - requires the optional parameter be an array
>
> call - requires the optional parameters be listed explicitly

Usually, a function may take any type of parameters - primitives and non-primitives. So, my questions are:

1. Could one of the optional parameters to the call method be of type `Array` or other non-primitive types?
2. Why does the above code exceeds call stack, when `call` is used?

Edit: Since there were 2 `call` methods used, my description was ambiguous. I made changes to clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
[].slice.call(arguments).reduce
              ^^^^^^^^^
```

so when you pass `[x]`, you're calling `reduce` on `[[x]]` and the first `val` becomes `[x]`. Then you call `flatten` once again with `[x]` and the story repeats itself.

On the other side, `apply(..., val)` will pass just `x` to `flatten`, thus reducing the nesting level by one.

If you're interested on how to use `apply` to flatten a deeply-nested array, this is possible without recursion:

```
while(ary.some(Array.isArray))
  ary = [].concat.apply([], ary);
```

Here's a small illustration of `call` vs `apply`:

```js
function fun() {
  var len = arguments.length;
  document.write("I've got " 
                 + len 
                 + " " 
                 + (len > 1 ? " arguments" : "argument")
                 + ": " 
                 + JSON.stringify(arguments)
                 + "<br>");   
}

fun.call(null, 123);
// fun.apply(null, 123); <-- error, won't work

fun.call(null, [1,2,3]);
fun.apply(null, [1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Thanks @georg . That clarifies it. Which means, call() can be passed with a non-primitive parameter as one of its optional argument - am i correct?

Comment: And that non-recursive deep flatten code - bloody awesome ! thanks a ton mate!

Comment: @Harish: added an example of call vs apply

Answer (score 2):

When you call `flatten.call(null, val)`, with `val` being an array, the `flatten` function receives as argument `val` what you passed as optional argument to `call` (the type isn't checked), so `arguments` is `[val]`.

You see your `val` array is inside an array. When you call `reduce`, `val`, inside the callback, will *still* be an array, you flattened nothing, that's why it never stops.

When you call `flatten.apply(null, val)`, with `val` being an array, the `flatten` function receives as arguments **the elements of** `val`, so `arguments` is identical to `val` (not `[val]`) : you've effectively unwrapped the array. That's why it works.