# Pass unknown number of parameters to JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

A pattern in some javascript libraries is to be able to pass any number of parameters to a function:

```
functiona(param1)
functiona(param1, param2, param3)
functiona(param1, param2)
```

I have an array of unknown length, and I'd like to pass all the array items as parameters to a function like `functiona()`. Is this possible? If so, what is the syntax for doing this?

Comment: It is not a duplicate of [What is the difference between call and apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)!

Comment: Yeah, I agree. This question isn't a duplicate, and while the other question does provide the answer, that answer is a small part of a larger discussion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you want is probably [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Usage:

```
var params = [param1, param2, param3];
functiona.apply(this, params);
```

As others noted, `functiona` declaration may use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), e.g.:

```
function functiona()
{
    var param1 = this.arguments[0];
    var param2 = this.arguments[1];
}
```

But it can use any number of normal parameters as well:

```
function foo(x, y)
{
    console.log(x);
}
foo.apply(this, [10, 0, null]); // outputs 10
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. And now I know a little more about .apply()

Answer (score 4):

Use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

> The `arguments` object is an Array-like object corresponding to the
>   arguments passed to a function.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, all parameters passed to a JavaScript function can be accessed using the `arguments` array within the function.

```
function foo () {
    console.log(arguments[0]); // -> bar
    console.log(arguments[1]); // -> baz
}

foo('bar', 'baz');
```