# Iterate over all properties, not just enumerable ones

Tags: javascript

This code iterates over just the enumerable properties of an object:

```
for (variable in object)
      statement
```

The following code iterates over all properties not just the enumerable ones:

```
function getAllPropertyNames(obj) {
  var result = [];
   while (obj) {
       Array.prototype.push.apply(result, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
       obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
   }
    return result;
}
```

1. When does the loop `while (obj)` break?
2. How do lines within the `while` block work to add the own property names of `obj` to `result`?

Comment: 1. When `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` returns `null`. 2. `Array.prototype.push.apply(result, Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));` is the same as `var tmp = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); result.push(tmp[0], tmp[1], ...)`. Learn more about `.apply` from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/218196

Comment: Why is Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) needed ?

Comment: @chefcurry7—so the OP can collect inherited properties too.

Comment: To clarify Felix's comments (which should be an answer), the `[[Prototype]]` of *Object.prototype* is null (see [*ECMAScript ed 6 §9.1*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)), which is the end of all built–in prototype chains. This isn't guaranteed to work with host objects, though for implementations consistent with the current standard, it probably will.

Comment: Oh, I see that ECMAScript ed 6 doesn't have host objects any more, it has [*exotic objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-exotic-object) defined by the non sequitur: *object that does not have the default behaviour for one or more of the essential internal methods that must be supported by all objects*. If something **must** be supported by **all objects**,how can some be allowed to not support it? Perhaps it should read: "*…by all built–in objects*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. When does the loop `while (obj)` break?

When there are no more prototypes in the prototype chain `getPrototypeOf` returns `null`. For regular objects, this happens when you try to get the prototype of `Object.prototype`.

> 2. How do lines within the `while` block work to add the own property names of `obj` to `result`?

`Array.prototype.push.apply(result, array)` passes each element in the `array` as argument to `result.push`. It is like calling `result.push(a[0], a[1], ...)` where `a` is `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)`.