# Javascript Reduce Function Not working

Tags: javascript, apply, reduce, arrow-functions

I am trying to work with higher order functions, in an attempt to be a better javascript developer.

The error I'm getting from the code below is `TypeError: myArray.reduce is not a function` I swear I'm following the correct design pattern.

```
function myFunction(myArray) {
    return myArray.reduce((prev, curr) => prev * curr);
}
var myArray = [3, 2, 3]
var myObject = myFunction.apply(myObject, myArray); // Will each element in array be multiplied?
```

Comment: Why not simply `var myObject = myFunction(myArray);` ?

Comment: What browser/version are you using? I know we saw that chrome 44 didn't support => but 47 or 48 did.

Comment: @Arnauld I am attempting to work with apply, arrow functions, and reduce patterns.

Comment: @klog I am using v52.

Comment: @ChrisClark Fair enough. Then you should use `myFunction.apply(myObject, [myArray])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) instead of [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

`.call` will pass in each object and pass them directly to the function, while `.apply` will take an array of parameters and pass them in as each separate variable.

You can see the effects below, with this simple script:

```js
function myFunction() {
    console.log(arguments);
}
var myArray = [3, 2, 3];

myFunction.call(null, myArray);
/*
 Will echo out {
   "0": [
    3,
    2,
    3
 ]}
 
 The first variable will contain the entire array
*/

myFunction.apply(null, myArray);
/*
 Will echo out {
  "0": 3,
  "1": 2,
  "2": 3
 }
 
 The first variable will be 3, the second 2, and the third 3
*/
```

Comment: Alternatively, `myFunction.apply(myObject, [myArray])`.

Comment: @ChrisClark more reading -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
var myObject = myFunction.apply(myObject, myArray);
```

Use

```
var myObject = myFunction.call(myObject, myArray);
```

Since function.prototype.apply method takes each items of array as a parameter. myArray parameter becomes 3, 2, 3 so It behaves like your function took 3 parameters.