# difference between functionName() and functionName.call(this)

Tags: javascript, inheritance, this

I research functional inheritance in javascript.
According the article I have read I have wrote the code:

```
function Base(){
    var enableVar = true

  this.enable = function(){
      console.log("enable");
        enableVar = true;
  }
   this.disable = function(){
      console.log("disable");
        enableVar = true;
  }
}

function Child(){
    Base.call(this);
}

new Child().enable();
```

this code works properly and I see message in console.

but I don't understand row:

```
Base.call(this);
```

for me it is `Base` function invocation with `this` replaced with `this` thus it is same with `Base();`

But looks like my state is wrong. I see error:

```
VM898:62Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).enable is not a function(…)
```

Please clarify difference for me.

### UPDATE

```
function funcB(){
  return this.a;
}

function funcA(){
  this.a = 2;   
  return funcB();
}
alert(funcA());
```

this code alerts 2 although I invoke `funcB` like `funcB();`

I really don't understand difference

Comment: See [What is the difference between call and apply?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/1529630)

Answer (score 2):

`functionName.call(obj)` calls `functionName` normally, with one main difference: Inside of `functionName`, `this` refers to `obj`. Normally `this` refers to  `window`, but making `this` reference `obj` is very good for inheritance because you can just keep on using `this` throughout all of your constructors.

## EDIT (To explain the update):

This is your code:

```
function funcB(){
  return this.a;
}

function funcA(){
  this.a = 2;   
  return funcB();
}
alert(funcA());
```

We will run through this step by step. The first thing to actually run is `alert(funcA());`, which calls `funcA()`. That code sees `this` as equal to `window` by default (window being javascript's Global Variable container). So what the computer sees as the next step (executing `funcA`) is this:

```
function funcA(){
  window.a = 2;   
  return funcB();
}
```

That code sets the global variable `a` to `2`, and will return whatever `funcB` returns, so we'll take a look at `funcB`. And remember, by default, javascript sets `this = window`, so `funcB` is actually

```
function funcB(){
  return window.a;
}
```

Remember that we set `window.a = 2` back in `funcA`, so `funcB` becomes

```
function funcB(){
  return 2;
}
```

Which means that `funcA` becomes

```
function funcA(){
  window.a = 2;   
  return 2;
}
```

Which means that `alert(funcA());` becomes `alert(2);`

Comment: `this` becomes the global object in sloppy mode. In strict mode it's `undefined`.

Comment: @gstackoverflow Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

First, think what `new` does. It creates a new object that is an instance of the function you specify. So `new Child` creates a new object based on `Child`

`Base.call(this)` means "run the `Base` function as if the newly created `Child` object as the context" (where "context" means "internal value of `this`). This means that the `enable` and `disable` functions are added to the new `Child` object.

Now think what calling `Base()` does. There is no new `Base` object. There is therefore no value of `this` within the function. The new `Child` object is not modified, so when you call `.enable()`, that function does not yet exist and you get the error that you mention.

Comment: @onesomeday**Now think what calling Base() does. There is no new Base object. There is therefore no value of this within the function.** Please clarify this

Comment: @gstackoverflow Correct, there is no new Base object. But in your first example, there is a new Child object, which inherits from Base.