# Emulate the JavaScript Function.prototype.call method, without using bind or apply?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering, is it possible to emulate the `Function.prototype.call` method?

I've implemented an emulation of `bind()`, the Douglas Crockford example is well known, by using `apply()` in a wrapper function.

Can I do the same for `call()`, without using `apply`, or `bind`? 
It's not something I would use of course in the real world, but just out of academic interest!

So far I havn't been able to figure this one, except using implicit binding - which has obvious drawbacks

```
'use strict';

// obj to bind as this, params is an array of parameters
function customCall( obj, params ){

  var funToCall = this;
  obj.funToCall = funToCall; // Implicit binding

  obj.funToCall(...params); // Obviously not a good idea
}

var objA = {
  a: "objA value"
};

function test(num1, num2){
  debugger;
  console.log(this.a);
  console.log(num1, num2);
}

test.customCall = customCall;
test.customCall(objA, [1,2]) //objA value, 1 2
```

Comment: Sorry but I'ma little confused of what you are asking. In your code, you have added a property to `obj`, so you are calling a function associated to object and not prototype. Also please refer [call vs apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply). Ideally every task that can be done using `apply` can be achieved using `call`. So *Can I do the same for call()*, **Yes**.

Comment: AFAIK you can't arbitrarily set `this` without using `call` `apply` or `bind`.

Comment: @Brian Implicit binding is how it's supposed to work. Hence why I stated "arbitrarily".