# Using bind in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, bind

How can I use bind() in the code below so that I dont lose the scope of "this"

```
this.getContactName(id, (error, contactName) => {
  if (error) return callback(error, null);

  // want to access "this" here e.g., 
  // this.indexScore = 1

  return callback(null, contactName);
});
```

Comment: `this.indexScore = 1` — Where is `indexScore`? What value of `this` do you want to bind?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call()` or `apply()` like this:

```
this.getContactName(id, (error, contactName) => {
  if (error) return callback.call(this, error);

  // want to access "this" here e.g., 
  // this.indexScore = 1

  return callback.call(this, contactName);
});
```

Or with `apply()`

```
this.getContactName(id, (error, contactName) => {
  if (error) return callback.apply(this, [ error ]);

  // want to access "this" here e.g., 
  // this.indexScore = 1

  return callback.apply(this, [ contactName ]);
});
```

---

Both methods bind the first argument as `this` value. The difference is, that `apply()` has an array of function arguments as a second parameter whereas `call()` just has one more argument than the initial function call (the first one is the functions's `this` value). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986909/3233827) for more information.

Comment: [deleted comment -- i wasn't paying attention]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
let me know if i'm wrong here

```
this.getContactName(id, (error, contactName) => {
  if (error) return callback(error, null);

  // want to access "this" here e.g., 
  // this.indexScore = 1

  return callback(null, contactName);
}).bind(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward answer is to wrap the anonymous function in parentheses and call `bind(this)` on it:

```
this.getContactName(id, ((error, contactName) => {

  if (error) return callback(error, null);
  return callback(null, contactName);

}).bind(this));
```

The more nuanced answer is that arrow functions don't bind their own `this` -- they are "lexically scoped" -- so this shouldn't actually be necessary.