# Add ability to add function into an existing custom waypoints function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Hello I have created a custom waypoint function which works well but I would like the ability to be able to add a function to it.

Here is the working custom waypoint function:

```
function createWaypoint (triggerElementId, animatedElement, className, offsetVal) {
    var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById(triggerElementId),
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'down') {
                jQuery(animatedElement).addClass(className);
                this.destroy();
            }
        },
        offset: offsetVal
    });
}

//Waypoint Instances
createWaypoint("x", ".y", "z", 500);
```

Next I would like the add the ability to add a function to the if statement and here is what I came up with:

```
function createWaypoint (triggerElementId, animatedElement, className, offsetVal, functionName) {
    var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById(triggerElementId),
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'down') {
                jQuery(animatedElement).addClass(className);
                functionName();
                this.destroy();
            }
        },
        offset: offsetVal
    });
}

function test() {
    alert('Hello World');
}

//Waypoint Instances
createWaypoint("x", ".y", "z", 500);
createWaypoint("x", null, null, null, test);
```

I added the functionName on line 1 and 7. Then I tried to call it on the very last line. The function "test" does not trigger and I get the error:

Uncaught TypeError: functionName is not a function.

Can anyone help out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `.call` or `.apply` ([more about them two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)):

```
function createWaypoint (triggerElementId, animatedElement, className, offsetVal, functionName) {
    var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: document.getElementById(triggerElementId),
        handler: function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'down') {
                jQuery(animatedElement).addClass(className);

                if(typeof functionName === 'function') {
                    functionName.call();
                } else {
                    console.log('functionName parameter is not a function.');
                }

                this.destroy();
            }
        },
        offset: offsetVal
    });
}

function test() {
    alert('Hello World');
}

//Waypoint Instances
createWaypoint("x", ".y", "z", 500);
createWaypoint("x", null, null, null, test);
```

---

**EDIT:** Actually, you should use `functionName.call(undefined)` or pass a `this` parameter from the scope of the function of your desire. It can be from the callback of the `handler` function, or from the `createWaypoint`, ie. `functionName.call(this)` or `functionName.call(mappedThis)`.

As [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) states:

> **thisArg** —
>       The value of this provided for the call to a function. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode , null and undefined will be replaced with the global object and primitive values will be converted to objects.

Comment: so basically just change `functionName.call();` to `functionName.call(this);` ? @omerowitz

Comment: Yes. Or pass `undefined` or `null` which will use the scope of the app/root.