# How does the [].push.apply work?

Tags: javascript, recursion, apply

can someone please explain me how does this line of code work.

```
[].push.apply(perms, permutation(arr.slice(0), start + 1, last));
```

This function generates an array of all permutations of an input array;

```
var permutation = function(arr, start, last){
  var length = arr.length;

  if(!start){
    start = 0;
  }

  if(!last){
    last = length - 1;
  }

  if( last === start){
    return [arr];
  }

  var temp;
  var perms = [];

  for(var i = start; i < length; i++){
    swapIndex(arr, i, start);
    console.log(arr);

    [].push.apply(perms, permutation(arr.slice(0), start + 1, last)); 

    swapIndex(arr, i, start);
  }

  return perms;
};
```

Comment: Are you interested in `apply` method ? This is one of the type you can call Javascript methods/function. You can read about `call` and `apply`. Probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply can help

Comment: What specifically is causing the confusion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[].push` creates a new array, then fetches `push` which is the same as [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) but with creating an unused object each time that needs to be garbage collected.

If you call `Array.prototype.push(5)` it wont work since `this` wouldn't be set to an array or something that extends an array. Thus you need to use either [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set `this` if you want to use an arbitrary function to work as a method.

If you have 
`Array.prototype.push.apply(thisObject, arrArguments)` is the same as
`thisObject.push(arrArguments[0], arrArguments[1], ..., arrArguments[n])` if `thisObject` has `push` in its prototype chain. Since `perms` is an array and has `push` in it's own prototype chain it could be replaced with:

```
perms.push.apply(perms, permutation(arr.slice(0), start + 1, last));
```

The use of `apply` is because `push` gets all the contents of the `permutations` array as arguments. thus if `permutations(....)` returned `[1,2,3]` it would be synonymous with `perms.push(1, 2, 3)`. You could write it without `apply` by calling `push` for each element:

```
for (var e of permutation(arr.slice(0), start + 1, last)) {
    perms.push(e);
}
```

And in ES6 you can simply use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which is the same as `apply` but simpler to comprehend:

```
perms.push(...permutation(arr.slice(0), start + 1, last))
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanded it is the same as:

`Array.prototype.push.apply(arrryToPushTo, ArrayOfItemsToPush)`

`apply()` is from [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and `Array.prototype.push` is a function.

Using an empty array instead of writing `"Array.prototype"` exposes the `push()` method that `apply()` can be called on and is done simply because `"[]"` is less characters to write than `"Array.prototype"`.