# When to use apply over call as we now have spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Below are `apply` and `call` functions:

`function.apply(context, [args])`

`function.call(context, arg1, arg2, ...)`

We know the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986909/4130867) between `apply` and `call`:

> The difference is that apply lets you invoke the function with
>   arguments as an array; call requires the parameters be listed
>   explicitly.

Now we have spread syntax, we can easily use `call` to do what `apply` does:

`function.call(context, ...[args])`

So with spread syntax, when do we use `apply` over `call`? I am curious if `apply` function can be retired.

Comment: Apply still makes sense if you're building function pipelines in a functional programming style. Read up on point free programming if you'd like to learn more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering that `args` is array-like iterable, it is

```
function.call(context, ...args);
// vs
function.apply(context, args);
```

And `apply` is shorter.

`apply` is native and thus faster than `call` with spread arguments. The difference can vary between browser versions and be negligible (recent Chrome/V8) or drastic (Firefox, older Chrome/V8). Depending on the case, this concern may be considered preliminary optimization.

The results can differ between browser versions, depending on the existence of optimizations for spread syntax and `arguments`. Previously array-like `arguments` could kill optimization in `apply`, notably in V8. This is no longer a problem in modern engines that support spread syntax.

Practical difference appears if arguments are array-like but not iterable. For instance, `arguments` became iterable [not so long ago](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/@@iterator#Browser_compatibility), `...arguments` will fail in older browser versions even if they support spread syntax. So `apply` is preferable here, because `call` would need a safety device:

```
function.call(context, ...Array.from(arguments));
// vs
function.apply(context, arguments);
```

On the other hand, there is practical difference if arguments are iterable but not array-like, too. Since `apply` accepts array-likes, `call` will be preferable and likely faster:

```
function.call(context, ...set);
// vs
function.apply(context, [...set]);
```