# Need Clarification on JavaScript apply Method

Tags: javascript

Can someone please point out what I am misunderstanding about apply. I have the following code:

```
function testFunc(input) {
  console.log(Array.isArray(input));
  console.log(input);
}

var obj = {};
var testArr = ["test1", true, 3];

testFunc(testArr);  // first call

testFunc.call(obj, testArr);  // second call

testFunc.apply(obj, testArr);  // third call
```

As expected, the first and second calls produce the outputs

**true** and **Array["test1", true, 3]**.

From my understanding of all that I've read on apply, the third call should also produce the same: apply is expecting *this* (obj) and an array-like argument.

However what I get is

**false** and **test1** (as a string).

How and why is the array being collapsed to its first element? What gives?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply

Comment: because it expects multiple arguments, not an array....

Comment: `apply` expects an array of arguments as the second argument. Thus `"test1"`, `true`, `3` are passed to `testFunc`.

Comment: `function testFunc(input) { console.log(arguments)`

Comment: `apply this with an array of arguments` `call this with arguments`