# jQuery: how can I use $(this) selector between multiple files?

Tags: jquery

I have a file "A" with

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {
    myFunction();
});
```

and a file "B" with

```
function myFunction() {
    $(this).hide();
};
```

It doesn't work because `$(this)` is undefined.

Is there a way I can pass the `$(this)` selector across multiple files?

Comment: why not `$('.myClass').mouseover(myFunction)`?

Comment: @Transamunos it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest solution I can think of:

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function(e) {
    myFunction(e.target);
});

function myFunction(element) {
    $(element).hide();
};
```

Since `this` inside `myFunction()` would return the Window object, I'd pass the element gathered from the jQuery event (`e.target`) and place that inside a jQuery function inside `myFunction()`. With this you can manipulate the exact element the event was triggered on.

Answer (score 0):

file A

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {
    myFunction($(this));
});
```

file B

```
function myFunction(element) {
    element.hide();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either reference the method directly or use [apply() or call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

```js
function myFunction() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
};


function myFunction2() {
    $(this).toggleClass('foo');
};

$('.myClass').mouseover(myFunction);


$('.myClass').mouseover(function () {
  myFunction2.apply(this);
});
```

```css
.active { color: red;}
.foo { background-color: yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myClass">2</div>
<div class="myClass">3</div>
```