# How to bind function to class to print custom text and object property?

Tags: javascript, class, bind

I'm trying to understanding how `bind()` works. In my JS script, I want to create an instance of a Rectangle class, and then call a function that prints text followed by a property of the rectangle, using the `bind()` function. Here's what I have:

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(height, width) {
      this.height = height;
      this.width = width;
    }
    getWidth() {
        return this.width;
    }
}

let Rectangle1 = new Rectangle(10, 20);

function func1(text) {
    console.log(`${text} + ${this.getWidth()}`)
}

let func2 = (text) => {
    func1.bind(Rectangle1, text)
}

func2('Rectangle width is: ')
```

The key is that I want to be able to call a function (`func2`) that contains only the beginning text.

Currently this code doesn't print anything.

What am I missing?

**SOLUTION:**

bind() returns a new function. So `func1.bind(Rectangle1, text)` doesn't *execute* a bound version of func1, it just *returns* the bound version of func1.

Solution is to change `func1.bind(Rectangle1, text)` to `func1.bind(Rectangle1)(text)`, which calls the bound version of func1 with `text` as input param.

Thanks @Pointy @Bergi and @James for your help.

Comment: `.bind()` returns a new function.  Your `func2()` makes a new function with `.bind()` but it doesn't call it or return it or anything.

Comment: `.call` instead of `.bind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want either

```
const func2 = (text) => {
    func1.call(rectangle1, text);
};
```

or

```
const func2 = func1.bind(rectangle1);
```

See [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1986896/1048572).