# The use of "this" is confusing me in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

Working with the JavaScript one of the confusing thing is when using `this`

```
var x = {  
  ele : 'test',
  init : function(){ 
    alert(this.ele);
  }
}
```

However when dealing with multiple object and especially events context of `this` changes and becomes confusing to keep track/understand.

So if anybody has better inputs/guidelines/thoughts/better practices, please share. Also I would like know if using `this` gives any (performance) advantage or what?

Comment: It's not just you -- this is one of the more confusing aspects of the language.  You should get some good answers;  I'm looking forward to reading them.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not about performance, it's about accessing a property of a specific instance of an object:-

```
x.init()
```

Would not display 'test' if you hadn't use `this` in the function.

Effectively the above line is the same as:-

```
x.init.call(x);
```

the first paramater in the use of `call` is assigned to `this` when the function is executed.

Now consider:-

```
var fn = x.init;  //Note no () so the function itself is assigned to the variable fn
fn();
```

Now you get nothing in the alert.  This because the above is effectively:-

```
fn.call(window);
```

In browser hosted Javascript the `window` object is synonymous with the global object.  When a function is called "in the raw" then the `this` defaults to the global object.

The classic error is doing something like this:-

```
var x = {
   ele: 'test';
   init: function(elem) { 
      elem.onclick = function() { alert(this.ele); }
   }
}
x.init(document.getElementById('myButton'));
```

However this doesn't work because the function attached to the onclick event is called by the browser using code like:-

```
onclick.call(theDOMElement)
```

Hence when the function is running `this` isn't what you think it is.

My usual solution to this situation is:-

```
var x = {
   ele: 'test';
   init: function(elem) {
      var self = this; 
      elem.onclick = function() { alert(self.ele); }
      elem = null;
   }
}
x.init(document.getElementById('myButton'));
```

Note the `elem = null` is IE memory leak work-around.

Comment: I think that should be x.init() not e.init() but the edit is <6 characters so I can't submit it.

Answer (score 6):

It is very confusing. It depends on how you call the function. Doug Crockford did a good write-up in his book [Javascript, the Good Parts](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596517748). The gist of it is in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118675/hi-everyone-what-do-these-this-mean-in-this-simple-javascript-program/1118938#1118938) to an otherwise badly formulated question.

And no, it's not about performance.

Answer (score 3):

To me, it helped a lot the following guideline: every time you see `this` think `owner`. The object who owns the variable name to which the function is assigned will become the `this`. If you cannot make sense to who owns it, then `this` will be window.

Answer (score 2):

A good and enlightening article on the `this` keyword is [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) (no pun intended). The article may clear things up for you, I know it did for me.

The essential rule is that the `this` keyword inside a function always refers to the function owner, and the key to understanding the consequences is understanding when functions are *referred* and when they are *copied*. See the beforementioned article for examples.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
var me = this;
```

outside of the

```
function(){
```

then you can refer to me inside the function()