# javascript function scope

Tags: javascript

Who can explain why result are [20, 20, 10, 10] in this code:

```
var x = 10;
var foo = {
  x: 20,
  bar: function () {
    var x = 30;
    return this.x;
  }
};

console.log(
  foo.bar(),
  (foo.bar)(),
  (foo.bar = foo.bar)(),
  (foo.bar, foo.bar)()
);
```

**Links to specification are welcomed**

Comment: in IE it seems the output is 20,20,undefined,undefined..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't point you at specification, but i can highly recommend reading [Douglas Crockford's "Javascript: The good parts"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596517742). This book will help you understand most of the weird but great features of JavaScript.

As of your question:

1. foo.bar(),
   `this` keyword in `bar` function is bound to `foo` object
2. (foo.bar)() is the same as above,
3. In javascript you can assign variables from right to left multiple times

   z = 3;
   x = (y = z);
   console.log(x); //3

functions are variables as anything else. So you are assigning the function `foo.bar` to `foo.bar`, but the parenthesis causes the assigned function to be returned, and then executed.

```
(foo.bar = foo.bar)(); 
//is the same as
var f = (foo.bar = foo.bar);
f(); 
//and this also the same as:
var f= foo.bar;
f();
```

The function returned from parenthesis is not bound to anything, so `this` will refer to global object, in case of browsers - to the `window` object.

4..  The clause (foo.bar, foo.bar)() is just alike:

```
a = (3, 4); //last value is returned, first just parsed.
//a contains 4

var f = (foo.bar, foo.bar); 
//f contains body of foo.bar function, 
f() // is executed  in the context of `global` object, eg. `window`.
```

Please read about `binding` of functions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148451/help-this-is-confusing-me-in-javascript) will be helpful for this.

Answer (score 0):

The first two function calls are equivalent. They are calling `foo`'s `bar` method within the context of `foo` – therefore the value returned by `this.x` is the value of `foo`'s `x` property, which is `20`.

The second two calls are both questionable/invalid syntax. Try running your code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and you'll that it spits out several errors and then chokes entirely. My best guess as to why they return `10` is that it's attempting to parse your code in a case where it really shouldn't and is getting confused. `10` might be returned because the browser cannot figure out what you're trying to do and is defaulting to global (window) scope where the value of `x` is `10`. This would also explain Ramesh Vel's comment that the second two values appear as `undefined` in IE. Due to the fact that the syntax is invalid, different implementations of JavaScript are likely to handle them differently.