# How do I make my function visible in the global scope

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have following javascript to make function `$E`

On `window.onload` it throws error that `$E` is not defined.

So my question is how do I make `$E` visible in the global scope so I can access it outside the `(function(){})();` function

```
window.onload = function() {
   $E("bhavik").warn();
}
(function() {
                function $E(s) {
                    return new ge(s)
                }
                function ge(sel) {
                    this.arg = sel;
                    return this;
                }
                ge.proto = ge.prototype = {warn: function() {
                        alert(this.arg)
                    }};
                ge.proto.hi=function(){alert("hi "+this.arg)}
                $E("bhavik").hi();
            })(window);
```

Comment: why your writing `function $E(){}` insite `(function(){});` write outside

Answer (score 3):

To make a variable visible in the global scope, set it on the `window` object.  For example:

```
function $E(s) {
   return new ge(s);
}
window.$E = $E;
```

Comment: i am still not able to access it

Answer (score 1):

[Javascript : How to create global functions & variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053292/javascript-how-to-create-global-functions-variables)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_global.asp

You should set a `window` variable to your `function` to make it accessible. These links will help.
Also you can define function outside and make it global.

For detailed study,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

[javascript function scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295281/javascript-function-scope)

Answer (score 1):

This made the function global from within another function when tested:

```
function test()
{
  window.$E = function() { alert('test'); };
}

test();
$E();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WEg4b/

So, to adapt it to your needs:

```
(function() {

                function ge(sel) {
                    this.arg = sel;
                    return this;
                }

                window.$E = function $E(s) { return new ge(s); };

                ge.proto = ge.prototype = {warn: function() {
                        alert(this.arg)
                    }};
                ge.proto.hi=function(){alert("hi "+this.arg)}
                $E("bhavik").hi();
            })(window);
```

Comment: Why when writing `function abc () { ... }` do not make it global and available by `abc()`?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it outside the anonymous function. By declaring all that code inside the module you are creating a new scope, isolated from all other code so, if you want that to be available in the global context, just declare it outside of that function.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the order of function declaration

```
(function() {
            function $E(s) {
                return new ge(s)
            }
            window.$E = $E;
            function ge(sel) {
                this.arg = sel;
                return this;
            }
            ge.proto = ge.prototype = {warn: function() {
                alert(this.arg)
            }};
            ge.proto.hi=function(){alert("hi "+this.arg)}
            $E("bhavik").hi();
        })(window);
window.onload = function() {
    $E("bhavik").warn();
```