# Still confused about JavaScript's 'this'

Tags: javascript

I've been reading through quite a few articles on the 'this' keyword when using JavaScript objects and I'm still somewhat confused. I'm quite happy writing object orientated Javascript and I get around the 'this' issue by referring the full object path but I don't like the fact I still find 'this' confusing.

I found a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148451/help-this-is-confusing-me-in-javascript) which helped me but I'm still not 100% sure. So, onto the example. The following script is linked from test.html with `<script src="js/test.js"></script>`

```
if (!nick) {
    var nick = {};
}

nick.name= function(){
    var helloA = 'Hello A';
    console.log('1.',this, this.helloA);

    var init = function(){
        var helloB = 'Hello B';
        console.log('2.',this, this.helloB);
    }

    return {
        init: init
    }
}();

nick.name.init();
```

**What kind of expected to see was**

```
1. Object {} nick.name, 'Hello A'
2. Object {} init, 'Hello B'
```

**But what I get is this?**

```
1. Window test.html, undefined
2. Object {} init, undefined
```

I think I understand some of what's happening there but I would mind if someone out there explains it to me.

Also, I'm not entirely sure why the first 'console.log' is being called at all? If I remove the call to the init function `//nick.name.init()` firebug still outputs `1. Window test.html, undefined`. Why is that? Why does  nick.name() get called by the window object when the html page loads?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Also, I'm not entirely sure why the first 'console.log' is being called at all?

```
nick.name = function(){
    // ...
}();
```

Here you define a function, call it immediately (hence `()`) and assign its return value (`{init: init}`) to `nick.name`

So the execution is:

1. Create a variable called `nick` if there isn't one with a non-falsey value already
2. Create an anonymous function that…
3. Creates a variable called `helloA` in its own scope
4. Outputs data using `console.log` containing "1" (as is), `this` (the `window` because the function is executing in the global context instead of as a method), and `this.helloA` (`window.helloA`, which doesn't exist.
5. Defines a function called `init`
6. Returns an object which gets assigned to `nick.name`
7. Then you call `nick.name.init()` which executes the `init` function in the context of `name`.
8. This defines `helloB`
9. Then it `console.logs` with "2" (as is), `this` (`name`), and `this.helloB` (`nick.name.helloB` - which doesn't exist)

So the first output you get is from `console.log('1.',this, this.helloA);`

I think your main problem is that you are confusing `this.foo` (properties on the object on which a method is being called) with variable scope (variables available to a function)

Comment: I didn't say it defines `helloB` in the context of `lowman`. It defines in the **scope** of `lowman`. A variable existing in a given scope is not the same as a property on an object.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help David. I've spent the morning creating some examples and I think I'm slowly getting it.

Answer (score 2):

1. `this` is defined on a per-function basis *when the function call is made*. When you call a function as `o.f()`, `this` will be `o` within the function, and when you call it as `f()`, `this` will be the global object (for browsers, this is the window). 
   You wrote `nick.name = function(){...}();` and the right-hand part is of the form `f()`, hence the `Window`.
2. `var foo = bar;` defines a local variable. It may not be accessed as `this.foo` (well, except when you're at global scope, but that's silly). To define a member, you usually write `this.foo = bar;` instead.

Comment: Victor, that was great answer thanks. Do you know why the window object called the function?

Comment: To be exact, when you call a function on its own (not as a member), `this` is the global object, which for web browsers is `Window`.

Answer (score 2):

It's much simpler if you think about `this` as a function, not as a variable. Essentially, `this` is a function which returns current "execution context", that is, the object the current function was "applied" to. For example, consider the following

```
function t() { console.log(this)}
```

this will return very different results depending upon how you call it

```
t() // print window

bar = { func: t }
bar.func() // print bar

foo = { x: 123 }
t.apply(foo) // print foo
```

Comment: Foo isn't be a function here so it won't have an apply method. I think you meant t.apply(foo). The apply method let's you define the execution context (value of this) explicitly as the function is invoked. (see also Function.call)

The flexibility JavaScript has in this sense can be a very powerful tool but it is also a source of great frustration, particularly before you get your head around it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply stereofrog. Can I just ask about foo.apply(t)? Was that a mistake? Should it be t.apply(foo) //print foo?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code does:

- It creates an object and assigns to the variable `nick`.
- It creates an anonymous function.
- It calls the function (in the window scope).
- It assigns the return value (an object containing the `init` property) to the `name` property of the object.
- It gets the value from the `init` property, which is a method delegate, and calls the method.

The anonymous function does this:

- It declares a local variable named `helloA` and assigns a string to it. (Creating a local variable doesn't add it as a property to the current object.)
- It logs `this` (window) and the `helloA` property (which doesn't exist).
- It creates an anonymous function and assignes to the local variable `init`.
- It creates an object with the property `init` and the value from the local variable `init`.

The anonymous function assigned to the `init` property does this:

- It declares a local variable named `helloB` and assigns a string to it. (Creating a local variable doesn't add it as a property to the current object.)
- It logs `this` (the object from the `name` property, not the `nick` variable), and the `helloB` property (which doesn't exist).

Comment: so should I use the this keyword when apply variables to an object i.e. this.helloA or does that make private varaibles become public?

Comment: @Nick: That depends on the current context. If the context is an object, you can use the `this` keyword to access the object. If it's the default context (window) you will be adding properties to the window object, thus making them global/public.