# Why "this" inside of a function's returning object window

Tags: javascript, function, this

there is two type of scope in javascript named
**function scope
global scope**

now i am executing this code

```
function abc()
{
alert(this);
}
abc();
```

abc call returning me [object Window]
Why?? function makes another scope so why it is representing window

Comment: "this" is why my friend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148451/help-this-is-confusing-me-in-javascript

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`this`, inside any function, will be the object on which the function is invoked. In your case, you are not invoking it on any object. So, by default `this` refer to `global` object, in your browser, it is the `window` object.

But in `strict` mode, if you invoke it like this, `this` will be `undefined`.

```
"use strict";
function abc() {
    console.log(this);    // undefined
}
abc();
```

Or

```
function abc() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(this);   // undefined
}
abc();
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword refers to the object the function belongs to, or the window object if the function belongs to no object.

**Reference**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

Your function is under global(window) object. I mean,

```
function abc()
{
    alert(this);
}
abc(); 
// or You can either call by
window.abc()
```

You can write your function under custom object

```
// Function under custom object
var customObj = {
    abc : function () {
        alert(this);
    }
};
customObj.abc()
```